# Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

The query I'm running is as follows, however I'm getting this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'guaranteed_postcode' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

```
SELECT `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `users`.`email`,
SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) AS `guaranteed_postcode`
FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
ON `users`.`id` = `locations`.`user_id`
WHERE `guaranteed_postcode` NOT IN #this is where the fake col is being used
(
 SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `region` IN
 (
  'australia'
 )
)
```

My question is: why am I unable to use a fake column in the where clause of the same DB query?

Answer (score 535, accepted):

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to
> refer to a column alias in a WHERE
> clause. This restriction is imposed
> because when the WHERE code is
> executed, the column value may not yet
> be determined.

Copied from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

As pointed in the comments, using HAVING instead may do the work. Make sure to give a read at this question too: [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having/18710763#18710763).

Comment: Cheers for the quick and accurate response! I've had a look into the HAVING clause and worked out a way to successfully run this query.

Thanks again.

Comment: In case anyone else has same prob as me which was using the aliased col in a where clause failing - swapping the 'WHERE' for 'HAVING fixed it straight away +1 good answer.

Comment: @megaSteve4 I did have the same problem! Using "HAVING" solved it smoothly. :)

Comment: This may or may not be important in your case, but `HAVING` executes slower than `WHERE`

Comment: @megaSteve4, What, simply that and it works? Then why couldn't MySQL be smart enough to do that automatically for us?

Comment: @DTs ultimately yes - it obviously depends on your query though.  More here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155937/mysql-having-vs-where

Comment: @DTs, Citation needed.

Comment: The reason `having` works is because the column values have to be computed by the time you get to the `having`. This isn't the case with `where`, as stated above.

Comment: @MillieSmith, That's true only for aggregate predicates in `having`. As we know, `having` can have non-aggregate predicates, just like `where`. In such a case, it isn't hard for the optimizer to convert that `having` predicate to an expanded `where` predicate. As such, citation needed. You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18710763/632951

Comment: @Pacerier The fact is that in this case MySQL is smarter, because is letting you choose if you want this condition to be checked before or after you get the fieldset. This is important in most of the queries. With "group by" for example the result is absolutely different.

Comment: @MillieSmith how do you evaluate where conditions without values? For me, the statement in the post makes no sense, because to check a condition (e.g. `a < 5`) you need the actual column value (e.g. value of  `a` to check `a < 5`).

Comment: Note after [December 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20091215124608/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-alias.html) the MySQL documentation got rephrased into "Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined."

Comment: before you leave assuming there also is no alternate available as well, do read below answered to this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25568879/10249156 Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Maybe my answer is too late but this can help others.

You can enclose it with another select statement and use where clause to it.

```
SELECT * FROM (Select col1, col2,...) as t WHERE t.calcAlias > 0
```

calcAlias is the alias column that was calculated.

Comment: This alternate way works with MySQL. Thanks @george-khouri

Answer (score 24):

As Victor pointed out, the problem is with the alias. This can be avoided though, by putting the expression directly into the WHERE x IN y clause:

```
SELECT `users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`,`users`.`email`,SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) AS `guaranteed_postcode`
FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
ON `users`.`id` = `locations`.`user_id`
WHERE SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) NOT IN #this is where the fake col is being used
(
 SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `region` IN
 (
  'australia'
 )
)
```

However, I guess this is very inefficient, since the subquery has to be executed for every row of the outer query.

Comment: @rodion, Yes I believe this is **severely** slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 23):

Standard SQL (or MySQL) does not permit the use of column aliases in a WHERE clause because

> when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

(from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html)). What you can do is calculate the column value in the *WHERE* clause, save the value in a variable, and use it in the field list. For example you could do this:

```
SELECT `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `users`.`email`,
@postcode AS `guaranteed_postcode`
FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
ON `users`.`id` = `locations`.`user_id`
WHERE (@postcode := SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4)) NOT IN
(
 SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `region` IN
 (
  'australia'
 )
)
```

This avoids repeating the expression when it grows complicated, making the code easier to maintain.

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with the documentation [that says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select/16715618#16715618) *"As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed."*?

Comment: That's definitely something to keep in mind. It has always worked for me though, I think the order of evaluation of the different parts of a statement had to be fixed (first WHERE, then SELECT, then GROUP BY,...) but I don't have a reference for that

Comment: A few examples: some [claim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select/24551337#24551337) that for them `select @code:=sum(2), 2*@code` works in MySQL 5.5, but for me in 5.6 the second column yields NULL on first invocation, and returns 2 times *the previous result* when run again. Interesting enough, both select `@code:=2, 2*@code` and `select @code:=rand(), 2*@code` do seem to work in my 5.6 (today). But those are indeed writing and reading in the SELECT clause; in your case you're setting it in WHERE.

Comment: @Joni, Why not just evaluate the condition twice? Surely MySQL is smart enough to optimize that.......

Comment: @Pacerier having to repeat the expression is still worse especially if it's complicated. I have not been able to confirm if MySQL implements common subexpression elimination.

Comment: @Joni, If it doesn't it's simply dumb. It should since we didn't use any non-deterministic functions like `rand()` `now()` etc.

Comment: `WHERE (@postcode := SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4)) NOT IN` This will be inefficient as it would run for each of the record in outer query.

Answer (score 8):

You can use HAVING clause for filter calculated in SELECT fields and aliases

Comment: @fahimg23 - Not sure.  I tried to find a reason why, but I can't!  Keep in mind the differences between `WHERE` and `HAVING`, though.  They're not identical.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=where+vs+having

Comment: UPDATE: It's because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/114558) provides the same solution but with more info.

Answer (score 2):

I am using mysql 5.5.24 and the following code works:

```
select * from (
SELECT `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `users`.`email`,
SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) AS `guaranteed_postcode`
FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
ON `users`.`id` = `locations`.`user_id`
) as a
WHERE guaranteed_postcode NOT IN --this is where the fake col is being used
(
 SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `region` IN
 (
  'australia'
 )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4)  for where conditon

```
SELECT `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `users`.`email`,
SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) AS `guaranteed_postcode`
FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations`
ON `users`.`id` = `locations`.`user_id`
WHERE SUBSTRING(`locations`.`raw`,-6,4) NOT IN #this is where the fake col is being used
(
SELECT `postcode` FROM `postcodes` WHERE `region` IN
(
 'australia'
)
)
```