# write query in ruby from SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write the below query in ruby.

```
select count(*), project_types.project_type_name,company_id from project_type_stages_questions,project_types where (project_type_stage_id in 
(select project_type_stages_id from project_type_stages where project_type_id in (select project_type_id from project_types))) group by project_type_stage_id,project_types.project_type_name,company_id
```

Comment: Read the following post, when a similar issue is explained:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894807/nested-queries-in-arel

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex sql to do, and you're going to use its result, you can pass it to the db manager:

```
sql = "select count(*), project_types.project_type_name,company_id from project_type_stages_questions,project_types where (project_type_stage_id in (select project_type_stages_id from project_type_stages where project_type_id in (select project_type_id from project_types))) group by project_type_stage_id,project_types.project_type_name,company_id"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

The public api don't provide much information, but it's [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute).

If you need an ActiveRecord::Relation as result, them I suggest to use Arel.