# I need a proper, less fragile, ActiveRecord happy way of writing this sql block in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need a less fragile way of writing this sql statement for ActiveRecord/Ruby 
right now i have :

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM  (SELECT id FROM collection_districts WHERE
district_id in (#{params[:material][:content_consumer]}, #{id}) group 
by colleciton_districts.id) tr  having count(*)=2;"
cd = CollectionDistrict.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Ive been trying a few different ways and it's not producing what I need and have spent many hours wrestling with it.  Hoping there is  a RoR guru who can help.  Thanks!

Comment: Some sample data and your expected result would be helpful

Comment: First step to create good sql statement or ActiveRecord queries: describe exactly what you want. Then other can help you here, or you may even find the solution yourself.

Comment: oh sorry Kristjan and Meier.  I expect to have an ID returned and nothing else. the raw SQL i wrote works fine in mysql workbench. just trying to move it into the Ruby environment.

Comment: You should *never* use interpolation with SQL. The code you have here has numerous SQL injection attack vunerabilities. Instead use bindings which are mostly immune to naive sql injection attacks. Mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble grasping the purpose of this query (or if it's even syntactically valid). So I'll leave you with some building blocks you can (hopefully) use to construct it.

Most of them are based on [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) that lies under the hood of ActiveRecord. All follow the format:

> #### Block
>
> Use cases
>
> ```
> general form (with meaningfully-named @variables-placeholders)
> example (with identifiers originating from the magic black box)
> useful tricks regarding this block {0+}
> ```
>
> Some extra information that gives some more insight on "what it is"

Since it's Arel, you'll need some understanding of SQL syntax in order to imagine an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your query. Some commonly used pieces can be expressed by ActiveRecord itself, but not all.

#### `FROM (subquery)`

For when you need to query not the table, but a set of rows generated by a subquery. You have to be careful though, as ActiveRecord will instantiate the records from the model you've started the query with (unless there's an association involved) and build conditions based on that model's table name. See "tricks" part.

```
@model.from(@subquery, @alias)
User.from(User.where(something: 42), 'super_users')
# A neat trick: query on a subset aliased to the same name as the table
# ActiveRecord's conditions will still work, but on a subset
# Known to break on some database servers: test before using
User.from(User.all, User.table_name)
# Placing  where-conditions on aliased table: use a hash of conditions
User.from(User.where(something: 42), 'su').where(super_users: {field: value})
```

Be cautious though: this allows you to produce bizarre relations that fetch data from one table, but are instantiated like sets of records from another one. Make sure your code is clear enough if you'll be using such effects intentionally.

If you're fetching from more than one source, you'll have to use a slightly different form, Arel-style explicit aliasing:

```
.from([table.as('alias'), table2.as('alias2'), ...])
```

#### Table-qualified column names

These can be used in a variety of ways: using in various SQL clauses (such as `group`), performing an implicit `INNER JOIN` (in form of `a.id = b.a_id`)... Specifically, `group` method can accept such a value.

```
Model.arel_table[:field]
District.arel_table[:id]
# writing .arel_table every time is tiresome and not DRY
# for referencing table columns more than once this makes sense:
districts = District.arel_table
districts[:id]
```

#### Wildcard (aka `*`)

Well, just because you have it and you need it. It is also usable in a variety of ways: for instance, using it in a qualified column identifier (like `districts[Arel.star]`) gives a wildcard on columns (like `districts.*`). The important part though, is that accepts chaining aggregate functions on top, like `Arel.star.count` (which is exactly `COUNT(*)`).

```
Arel.star # => "*" Well, there's nothing more to it
Arel.star.count # => "COUNT(*)"
```

It's just a node of Arel's SQL AST. It can be used anywhere where it's valid in equivalent SQL. In Rails' `select` method, for instance.

#### `IN`-condition

This one's easy for when you want to constraint a field to have one of the given values. This one is as easy as passing in an array of possible values into `where`:

```
Model.where(field: [value1, value2])
User.where(id: [1, 2]) # SELECT users.* WHERE users.id IN (1, 2)
```

#### Arel-style conditions

This is where the syntax gets ugly. Well, sometimes you have to deal with it. For instance, `having`-clause may force you to do this. These conditions can also be fed into `where`.

```
expression.operator(expression)
a[:id].eq(b[:a_id]) # a.id = b.a_id
```

There's quite a bunch of operators available, they more-or-less map to English terms used to describe them: `lt` for "less than", `lteq` for "less than or equal", `matches` for `LIKE` or `ILIKE`, `in` for, well, `IN`... Here's a (possibly incomplete) list (found in `Arel::Predications` module):

```
  does_not_match      eq_all  gt_any    in      lt_all    lteq_any     not_eq      not_in_all
  does_not_match_all  eq_any  gteq      in_all  lt_any    matches      not_eq_all  not_in_any
  does_not_match_any  gt      gteq_all  in_any  lteq      matches_all  not_eq_any
  eq                  gt_all  gteq_any  lt      lteq_all  matches_any  not_in
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` doesn't do anything fantastic to support nested queries, but you can pull your raw SQL into [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) (which `ActiveRecord` sits on top of) using techniques from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894807/nested-queries-in-arel):

```
inner_query = YourModel.where(:stuff => "foo")
outer_query = YourModel.scoped  # cheating, need an ActiveRelation
outer_query = outer_query.from(Arel.sql("(#{inner_query.to_sql}) as results")).
                          select("*")
```

---

If you don't mind making two queries, you can do it in a very `ActiveRecord`y way by first taking the IDs, then looking up the full objects.

```
district_ids = params[:material][:content_consumer].split(',') + [id]
ids = CollectionDistrict.where(district_id: district_ids)
                        .group(:id)
                        .having('count(*) = 2')
                        .pluck(:id)
CollectionDistrict.find(ids)
```

---

And finally if the list of districts is reasonably sized, you could load them up and do it in Ruby with some nice functional chaining.

```
CollectionDistrict.where(district_id: district_ids)
  .group_by(&:id)
  .select { |id, collection_districts| collection_districts.size == 2}
  .map(&:last)
  .flatten
  .uniq
```

---

These will all have different performance characteristics, so if that's a concern you should do some benchmarking. If you're not worried about performance yet, I like the readability of the latter two options.

Answer (score 0):

once again, scopes can reduce the complexity of your query

```
class ColletionDistrict < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :districs, ->(*d) {
    where(district_id: d.flatten.compact.uniq)
  }
end

CollectionDistrict.districts(params[:material][:content_consumer]).select(:id).group(:id).having('count(id) > 2')
```