# Rails Arel: How to create query with "from" and subquery

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have searched many places but found no result. I want to have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM( sub_query ) AS virtual_table
```

But it looks like Arel doesn't allow me to do so. Arel just allow some structure such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name as virtual_table
```

How can I overcome this limit in Arel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894807/nested-queries-in-arel

Comment: @Vimsha thanks. but my problem is: nested query is not from any normal table. For example, I use `generate_series` for generate a table and then using for joining later.

Comment: I think Arel can do this, but this seems like a shoe-in for a [database view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic), which would reduce complexity.