# WHERE vs HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having-clause

Why do you need to place columns you create yourself (for example `select 1 as "number"`) after `HAVING` and not `WHERE` in MySQL?

And are there any downsides instead of doing `WHERE 1` (writing the whole definition instead of a column name)?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

> Why is it that you need to place columns you create yourself (for example "select 1 as number") after HAVING and not WHERE in MySQL?

`WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` is applied after (and can filter on aggregates).

In general, you can reference aliases in neither of these clauses, but `MySQL` allows referencing `SELECT` level aliases in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`.

> And are there any downsides instead of doing "WHERE 1" (writing the whole definition instead of a column name)

If your calculated expression does not contain any aggregates, putting it into the `WHERE` clause will most probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 363):

All other answers on this question didn't hit upon the key point.

Assume we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And have 10 rows with both id and value from 1 to 10:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `value`) VALUES (1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(4, 4),(5, 5),(6, 6),(7, 7),(8, 8),(9, 9),(10, 10);
```

Try the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `value`>5; -- Get 5 rows
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` HAVING `value`>5; -- Get 5 rows
```

You will get exactly the same results, you can see the `HAVING` clause can work without GROUP BY clause.

---

Here's the difference:

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `v`>5;
```

The above query will raise error: Error #1054 - Unknown column 'v' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT `value` v FROM `table` HAVING `v`>5; -- Get 5 rows
```

`WHERE` clause allows a condition to use any table column, but it cannot use aliases or aggregate functions.
`HAVING` clause allows a condition to use a selected (!) column, alias or an aggregate function.

**This is because `WHERE` clause filters data before select, but `HAVING` clause filters resulting data after select.**

So put the conditions in `WHERE` clause will be more efficient if you have many many rows in a table.

Try `EXPLAIN` to see the key difference:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `value` v FROM `table` WHERE `value`>5;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | range | value         | value | 4       | NULL |    5 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+

EXPLAIN SELECT `value` v FROM `table` having `value`>5;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | index | NULL          | value | 4       | NULL |   10 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

You can see either `WHERE` or `HAVING` uses index, but the rows are different.

Comment: I appreciate that you mentioned EXPLAIN!

Comment: Because of  HAVING clause filters data after select, WHERE clause will be more effective. So if this is true, when must we use HAVING instead of WHERE?

Comment: @grep In case you have to filter data after select, you need HAVING clause, usually we use it with GROUP BY clause, e.g.:  
`SELECT value, COUNT(*) frequency FROM table GROUP BY value HAVING frequency > 10`

Comment: @Fishdrowned, Why does MySQL even allow non-aggregate predicates in having in the first place?

Comment: Excellent post.  A couple of suggested clarifications: Change `...HAVING clause can use both column and alias.` to `...HAVING clause can use either column or alias.` and change `...WHERE clause will be more effective` to `...WHERE clause will be more efficient`

Comment: The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: I'm confused which `row` you are referring in your last statement. Can you  clarify?

Comment: This answer does not even begin to explain `WHERE` vs `HAVING` - It just shows the non-standard behaviour of MySQL when one uses `HAVING` incorrectly.

Answer (score 69):

The main difference is that `WHERE` cannot be used on grouped item (such as `SUM(number)`) whereas `HAVING` can.

The reason is the `WHERE` is done *before* the grouping and `HAVING` is done *after* the grouping is done.

Answer (score 42):

`HAVING` is used to filter on aggregations in your `GROUP BY`.

For example, to check for duplicate names:

```
SELECT Name FROM Usernames
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: It's true to some extant. You can still put your whole 'Where' in the having clause.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having#comment48406726_18710763

Answer (score 12):

These 2 will be feel same as first as both are used to say about a condition to filter data. Though we can use ‘having’ in place of ‘where’ in any case, there are instances when we can’t use ‘where’ instead of ‘having’. This is because in a select query, ‘where’ filters data before ‘select’ while ‘having’ filter data after ‘select’. So, when we use alias names that are not actually in the database, ‘where’ can’t identify them but ‘having’ can.

Ex: let the table Student contain student_id,name, birthday,address.Assume birthday is of type date.

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE YEAR(birthday)>1993; /*this will work as birthday is in database.if we use having in place of where too this will work*/

SELECT student_id,(YEAR(CurDate())-YEAR(birthday)) AS Age FROM Student HAVING Age>20; 
/*this will not work if we use ‘where’ here, ‘where’ don’t know about age as age is defined in select part.*/
```

Comment: This real life example clarifies fully the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

Comment: Clearly shows the difference between Having and where. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> *WHERE* filters before data is grouped, and *HAVING* filters after data is grouped. This is an important distinction; rows that are
>   eliminated by a *WHERE* clause will not be included in the group. This
>   could change the calculated values which, in turn(=as a result) could affect which
>   groups are filtered based on the use of those values in the *HAVING*
>   clause.

And continues,

> *HAVING* is so similar to *WHERE* that most DBMSs treat them as the same
>   thing if no *GROUP BY* is specified. Nevertheless, you should make that
>   distinction yourself. Use *HAVING* only in conjunction with *GROUP BY*
>   clauses. Use *WHERE* for standard row-level filtering.

Excerpt From:
 [Forta, Ben. “Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes (5th
 Edition) (Sams Teach Yourself...).”.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135182794)

Answer (score 1):

Having is only used with aggregation but where with non aggregation statements
If you have where word put it before aggregation (group by)