# what's the difference between WHERE and HAVING

Tags: t-sql

It looks like both **WHERE** and **HAVING** help filter rows. I wonder if, instead of having to HAVING, I can use **WHERE ... AND**.

I'm a little confused.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explanation and query samples in this fine article: [Where Vs Having / Difference between having and Where clause](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Where_Vs_Having_Clause.aspx)

Answer (score 35):

You use "WHERE" clauses to select rows for inclusion in the dataset *before* grouping operations have happend (GROUP BY).  You use HAVING clauses to filter rows *after* grouping.

So like if you're aggregating a sum or a maximum or a minimum, you can use HAVING predicates to check the aggregated values on the candidate rows.

Answer (score 10):

There are some subtleties and intricacies, but quick description is a comparison: HAVING is to GROUP BY as WHERE is to SELECT.

In other words, if you think of HAVING as a WHERE clause that gets applied after the GROUP BY clause, things start to make sense.

Comment: So you mean, the difference between the 2 is mostly the fact that one is applied to SELECT and the other to GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the Having statement with Group By, typically as a way to filter on an aggregate column.

You can get more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Where_Vs_Having_Clause.aspx).