# MySQL can't ORDER BY using HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can any one advise me of a problem im having with ordering results in mysql

**The Problem**

Can not order by any column other than distance

```
SELECT * , (
            (
            (
            ACOS( SIN( (
            '56.3168322' * PI( ) /180 ) ) * SIN( (
            `lat` * PI( ) /180 )
            ) + COS( (
            '56.3168322' * PI( ) /180 )
            ) * COS( (
            `lat` * PI( ) /180 )
            ) * COS( (
            (
            '-5.414989099999957' -  `lng`
            ) * PI( ) /180 )
            )
            )
            ) *180 / PI( )
            ) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
            ) AS  `distance` 
            FROM  `incidents` 
            HAVING  `distance` <=3
            ORDER BY  `distance` ASC 
            LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When I try to order column based on date in the date_incident row for example

```
 SELECT * , (
                (
                (
                ACOS( SIN( (
                '56.3168322' * PI( ) /180 ) ) * SIN( (
                `lat` * PI( ) /180 )
                ) + COS( (
                '56.3168322' * PI( ) /180 )
                ) * COS( (
                `lat` * PI( ) /180 )
                ) * COS( (
                (
                '-5.414989099999957' -  `lng`
                ) * PI( ) /180 )
                )
                )
                ) *180 / PI( )
                ) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
                ) AS  `distance` 
                FROM  `incidents` 
                HAVING  `distance` <=3
                ORDER BY  `date_incidents` ASC 
                LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In the above it does not sort but still returns results.

Any help would be great on this.

Comment: Be careful when using transcendental math functions (eg: `SIN(x)`, `COS(x)`, etc.) to calculate distances. They are very slow. For larger tables, performance will suffer.

Comment: `HAVING` implies that some sort of aggregation is going on, I believe. Should the `HAVING` be changed to `WHERE distance <=3` instead? That may be the problem. I don't see any aggregation going on here. That may be the problem--with the `distance` field in the `HAVING` clause, it could be implying `GROUP BY distance`.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee `WHERE` can't be used with aliases in the same `SELECT`, it can only be used with columns and aliases in tables and subqueries.

Comment: Could you post the table structure? This could help troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL does not permit the `HAVING` clause to name any column not found in the `GROUP BY` clause unless it is enclosed in an `aggregate function`.but MySQL allows referencing any aliases in `HAVING` clause. ex:

```
SELECT name, AVG(age) AS a FROM tables
   GROUP BY name
   HAVING a > 50;
```

Comment: Standard SQL might not, but MySQL allows referencing any aliases in HAVING. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having

Comment: Also see the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-alias.html)