# How can I make two condition in having clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to:

```
domain      |   file      | Number 
------------------------------------     
aaa.com     | aaa.com_1   | 111
bbb.com     | bbb.com_1   | 222
ccc.com     | ccc.com_2   | 111
ddd.com     | ddd.com_1   | 222
eee.com     | eee.com_1   | 333
```

I need to query the number of `Domains` that share the same `Number` and their `File` name ends with `_1`. I tried the following:

```
select count(domain) as 'sum domains', file
from table 
group by Number
having
count(Number) >1 and File like '%\_1';
```

It gives me:

```
sum domains | file
------------------------------
2           | aaa.com
2           | bbb.com
```

I expected to see the following:

```
sum domains | file
------------------------------
1           | aaa.com
2           | bbb.com
```

Because the `Number` 111 appears once with `File` ends with `_1` and `_2`, so it should count 1 only. How can I apply the 2 conditions that I stated earlier correctly ?

Comment: MySQL is free to choose any value from non-aggregated columns in each group, so the value selected for `file` is indeterminate.  Your expected output shows a count of 2 against `bbb.com` - but there is only one `bbb.com` domain/file in your table - why do you expect that `file` value in the second group (which presumably has `Number=222`) and not, for example, `ddd.com`?

Comment: As you said, the selected value for `file` is undetermined. I put `bbb.com` as example. But the problem is not in the `file`. my problem in the `sum domains`. My query result counts counts the files that do not end with `_1`, which I do not want and I put a condition in the `having` clause but it seems there is something wrong.

Comment: Well, my comment was really intended to point out that the objective of your query is unclear.  If the value returned for `file` is unimportant to you, why select it at all?  It's more normal to select the column(s) on which one has grouped the results: i.e. `Number` in this case.  To answer your question, it seems you *probably* intend for the filter on `file` to occur prior to the grouping - i.e. in a `WHERE` clause rather than in the `HAVING` clause (which is performed on the grouped results, after aggregation such as `COUNT(*)` has already been performed).

Comment: You are right. the `file` is kind of meaningless. It is more meaningful to use the 'Number'. If I used `where' for to filter files wich ends with `_1`, then how can I add another condition which is that the `Number` appeared more than once. i.e, I need to query the number of files in `File` that end with `_1` and share the same `Number`.

Comment: Do you want those `Number`s which have more than one `file` ending with `1`, or those `NUmber`s which have more than one record at least one of which ends in `1`?

Comment: None of them. I need to know the cases in which many (more than one) `file`that ends with `_1` use the same `number`. For example, the `number` 222 have two occurrence of files ending with `_1`. So, I want to print the counter of occurrence (i.e, 2) and the `number` that these two files that ends with `_1` have shared. i.e, my output should be: 2 | 2222

Comment: So then: ``SELECT Number, COUNT(*) AS `sum domains` FROM `table` WHERE file LIKE '%\_1' GROUP BY Number HAVING `sum domains` > 1``

Comment: Wouldn't you also expect a result for `ddd.com`, since it qualifies just as much as `aaa.com`?

Comment: Yes, but when you use `group by`, it will print one item in the group. So, in the group of which has `number` is `222`, it will print normally the first item which is in my case `bbb`. `ddd` is also member of the group that has the `number` is `222`. there are other ways needed to print all items in the group. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897748/how-to-print-every-item-resulted-from-group-by-statement

Comment: @eggyal: Can you add it as a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As documented under `SELECT` Syntax:

> The `HAVING` clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization.

In other words, it is applied *after* the grouping operation has been performed (in contrast with `WHERE`, which is performed *before* any grouping operation).  See [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2905292).

Therefore, your current query first forms the resultset from the following:

```
SELECT   COUNT(domain) AS `sum domains`, file
FROM     `table`
GROUP BY Number
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4222/1/0):

```
| SUM DOMAINS |      FILE |
---------------------------
|           2 | aaa.com_1 |
|           2 | bbb.com_1 |
|           1 | eee.com_1 |
```

As you can see, the values selected for the `file` column are merely one of the values from each group—as documented under [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Your current query then proceeds to filter these results according to your `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING   COUNT(Number) > 1 AND file LIKE '%\_1'
```

With the values of `file` selected above, every single group matches on the second criterion; and the first two groups match on the first criterion.  Therefore the results of [the complete query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4222/2/0) are:

```
| SUM DOMAINS |      FILE |
---------------------------
|           2 | aaa.com_1 |
|           2 | bbb.com_1 |
```

Following [your comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896857/how-can-i-make-two-condition-in-having-clause#comment19148447_13896857), you want to filter the records on `file` *before* grouping and then filter the resulting groups for those containing more than one match.  Therefore use `WHERE` and `HAVING` respectively (and select `Number` instead of `file` to identify each group):

```
SELECT   Number, COUNT(*) AS `sum domains`
FROM     `table`
WHERE    file LIKE '%\_1'
GROUP BY Number
HAVING   `sum domains` > 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4222/3/0):

```
| NUMBER | SUM DOMAINS |
------------------------
|    222 |           2 |
```

Answer (score 6):

i am using by following

```
having ( SUM(qty) > 4 AND SUM(qty) < 15 )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The braces, showing that you can string clauses similar to an inline select helped me with the syntax.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Next time i will explain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the file name in the `SELECT` statement if it is not also in the `GROUP BY`.  You have to get your `GROUP BY` result than `JOIN` back to the original and add the filter logic like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 select count(domain) as 'sum_domains', Number
 from table 
 group by Number
 having
 count(Number) >1
) result
join table t on result.Number = t.Number
WHERE file like '%\_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the nested query below:

```
  select count(domain) as 'sum domains', domain as fileName
  from 
   (select domain, file from tableName
    group by Number
    having count(Number) >1) as temp
  WHERE file like '%\_1';
```

Comment: @user1810868 I used the file in the where clause. Updated to use domain. Try now. Use the right table name in the query.

Comment: It does not come. The file is the field that contains `_1`.

Comment: @user1810868 Corrected the query. Please try and let me know.