# How to print every item resulted from group by statement

Tags: mysql

I have made a statement that used group by. Now, I need to know the details for every record but I need to perform this at one statement.

For example: I made the following query to query about the files that ends with `_1` and share the same `number`:

SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS `sum domains` 
FROM table
WHERE file  LIKE '%_1' 
GROUP BY number HAVING `sum domains` > 1

So, if I have the following table:

```
domain      |   file      | Number 
------------------------------------     
aaa.com     | aaa.com_1   | 111
bbb.com     | bbb.com_1   | 222
ccc.com     | ccc.com_2   | 111
ddd.com     | ddd.com_1   | 222
eee.com     | eee.com_1   | 333
qqq.com     | qqq.com_1   | 333
```

The result of the query is (the `number` that is shared by more than `file` and the count of the `file`(s) that ends with `_1` and shared this number):

```
number | sum domains
------------------------
222    | 2
333    | 2
```

What I need to do is to print out the file names. I need:

```
number | file
------------------------
222    | bbb.com_1 
222    | ddd.com_1
333    | eee.com_1
333    | qqq.com_1
```

How can I do this since `group by` clause does not allow me to print the `file`(s) ?

Comment: I have a lot of records in every group. This will not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JOIN` your query back against the main table as a subquery, to get the original rows and filenames:

```
SELECT 
  main.number, 
  main.file
FROM 
  table AS main
  /* Joined against your query as a derived table */
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS sum domains 
    FROM table
    WHERE RIGHT(file, 2) = '_1' 
    GROUP BY number 
    HAVING sum domains > 1
    /* Matching `number` against the main table, and limiting to rows with _1 */
  ) as subq ON main.number = subq.number AND RIGHT(main.file, 2) = '_1'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb05b/6

Note that I have replaced your `LIKE '%_1'` with `RIGHT(file, 2) = '_1'`. Hard to tell which will be faster without a benchmark though.

Comment: I was going to say, if the OP uses `LIKE`, they need to escape the underscore since it's a wildcard. (`LIKE '%\_1'`)