# MySQL, Filtering by number of occurrences of a specific foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to discover the foreign keys which appear more than once for all rows in table and return those foreign keys via a subquery.

Using `GROUP BY` on the column I was able to visualize the `COUNT` of each foreign key:

```
SELECT orders_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM order_history
GROUP BY orders_id
```

but then when I augment it with a WHERE clause in an attempt to filter, like this:

```
SELECT orders_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM order_history
GROUP BY orders_id
WHERE count > 1
```

I get an error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE count > 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4
```

apparently `count` is ineligible for comparisons at the point `WHERE` is evaluated?

**: Post answer update :**

Thanks for the speedy responses! `HAVING` is exactly what I was missing. I found this question helpful expansion of the topic: [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Comment: The error is common - *the order of components matters in an SQL select statement*. As in this case, `WHERE`, if present, must always come before `GROUP BY`; the fundamental issue here is *invalid syntax* and not an unbound identifier. (Selects can be nested, but there are better ways to handle this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply filtering to an aggregate value like `COUNT(),SUM(),MAX(),MIN()`, use a `HAVING` clause rather than `WHERE`.

```
SELECT orders_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM order_history
GROUP BY orders_id
HAVING count > 1
```

The syntax error results from the fact that a `WHERE` clause must precede the `GROUP BY` clause. However, even if it was in the right place, it would still error because the `count` alias would be unknown at the time the `WHERE` clause was computed.

From the [MySQL `SELECT` syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> A HAVING clause can refer to any column or alias named in a select_expr in the SELECT list or in outer subqueries, and to aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks for being complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `where clause` with `group by clause`, in this case you have to use `having`

```
SELECT orders_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM order_history
GROUP BY orders_id
having count > 1
```