# SQL with Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

First -- I have read about 7 pages of posts with similar titles but couldn't find the right insight for my challenge

My SQL:

```
SELECT name, address, lat, lng, city, state, phone, zip, info
    , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.4969') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122.2674') ) + sin( radians('37.4969') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM myhealthfinder_map 
HAVING distance < '50'  and location = '2'  
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

I get the error message: Invalid query: Unknown column 'location' in 'having clause'

if instead of HAVING I just make it WHERE location = '2' then it works fine [it finds the column] (but I need the distance selector).

Any suggestion on how to knock this down?

Comment: Should you select the column location too

Comment: You have `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's ok in mysql when you have calculated columns.  In SQL Server (maybe others?) it's a no-go.  So that's why `HAVING` is ok on the column `distance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both WHERE and HAVING.  `HAVING` is used for aggregated and calculated columns.  And `WHERE` on plain old columns.

```
SELECT name, address, lat, lng, city, state, phone, zip, info
    , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.4969') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122.2674') ) + sin( radians('37.4969') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM myhealthfinder_map 
WHERE location = '2' 
HAVING distance < '50'  
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

More explanation found here [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Comment: Rocking -- I had tried HAVING and the WHERE with no love, but flip them around and SUCESS.  Thank you kind person.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`. You can try this instead

```
SELECT name, address, lat, lng, city, state, phone, zip, info, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.4969') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122.2674') ) + sin( radians('37.4969') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM myhealthfinder_map 
 WHERE location = '2' AND
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.4969') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122.2674') ) + sin( radians('37.4969') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 50
 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

It's not pretty, but it should work.