# set a new column and be an unknown column in where clause (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with the `WHERE CLAUSE` in mysql query. I want to filter data from a column that I directly defined.
this is my example table (named MEMBER) :

```
++++++++++++++++
title | name   |
++++++++++++++++
leaf  | andro  |
moon  | sheila |
rocks | sarah  |
```

I run this query :

```
SELECT *, IF( title = "moon", "fly","on earth") AS status FROM MEMBER;
```

and the result :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
title | name   | status |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
leaf  | andro  |on earth|
moon  | sheila |fly     |
rocks | sarah  |on earth|
```

But why when I added a `WHERE CLAUSE` to filter the `status` column at the end of the query it returns an error?
this is the query:

```
SELECT *, IF( title = "moon", "fly","on earth") AS status 
FROM MEMBER 
WHERE status = "fly";
```

the error message is :
`#1054 - Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'` 
the 'directly defined' column that i mean is `status` column, it's not exist in the table but i created/defined it in the query. 
I have tried to create `status` column in the table and it has null value, so when i run the second query (that containing `WHERE CLAUSE`), it would returns `zero result`. 
i know another way to filter the data, i can use this query :

```
SELECT *, IF( title = "moon", "fly","on earth") AS status 
FROM MEMBER 
WHERE title = "moon";
```

but I can't do the filter by using that query in my case. I have to filter the `status` column. 
Please don't see this question as a fool question, because this is the case that i have.
So, anybody has the alternatives?

Comment: You can not use column `alias` in `WHEN` clause.  You can create an artificial sub-query, for example.

Comment: did you mean `WHERE`?
what is artificial sub-query? and show me the example, please! :D

Comment: Yes, `WHERE` sorry about that.

Comment: thanks! that's the answer of my "why" question that i looking for

Comment: Example with *artificial* sub-query has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`HAVING` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2905292/1190388) to set a condition on `status` field. The field `status` was aggregated outside of the table itself and hence, `WHERE` can do nothing.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    IF( title = "moon", "fly","on earth") AS status 
FROM MEMBER 
HAVING status = "fly";
```

Comment: Wow! thank you! it works well.. I ever using `HAVING` in my previous program, but why do i forget!? :D

Answer (score 2):

With sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT *, IF( title = "moon", "fly","on earth") AS status  
 FROM MEMBER 
) sq 
WHERE status = "fly";
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5834f2/4)

Comment: yes, it works well too! but, i think it will spend more time to filter thousands of data. my program has thousands of  data.. tq

Comment: Just as an FYI: `HAVING` does its filtering **after** all the data was fetched and aggregated.

Comment: Ok!  that's a new knowledge for me. tq

Comment: This is a solution but has a minor performance issue with regards the use of a subquery.