# Running into Error Code 1111 on MySQL how can I fix it?

Tags: sql, error-code, mysql-error-1111

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE P_CODE = (SELECT P_CODE FROM LINE WHERE LINE_TOTAL > AVG(LINE_TOTAL));

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and an explanation of what you want to do.  The query doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is the ERROR message I keep receiving. This is what i'm trying to do List all Products with a total quantity sold greater than the average quantity sold. 

20:11:40 SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE P_CODE = (SELECT P_CODE FROM LINE WHERE LINE_TOTAL > AVG(LINE_TOTAL)) LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function 0.000 sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Code 1111. Invalid use of group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141968/error-code-1111-invalid-use-of-group-function)

Comment: @Renat I saw that but I was confused as to what to Group By I tried adding HAVING but that did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE P_CODE in (SELECT P_CODE 
                 FROM LINE 
                 WHERE LINE_TOTAL > (select AVG(LINE_TOTAL) from LINE)
                );
```