# Using max in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

for a particular query where I need to show an entire tuple, based on the max value of a particular field, for this I need to use max at where clause, how can I use it? Right now I am achieving the same by limit 1

```
select * from  
  (select count(some_field) as field1 ..........order by field1 desc) as kil 
limit 1
```

Comment: What's the main problem with the query you have? Performance? Incorrect result?

Comment: Is there any other better method to achieve the same, I mean to boost performance? @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having

Believe you want Having.

Comment: Do you have a `group by` in your inner query? You may need to show a bit more detail on your inner query to give a chance to optimize it.

Comment: Perhaps, you should show sample data, and which row(s) you want back and explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from some_table
where field1 = (select max(field1) from some_table)
```

Note that your original query will return one row, but this query may return multiple rows if there are multiple rows that share the same maximum value. To duplicate the same behaviour, you would still have to add `limit 1` to the end of this query.

Comment: the inner query needs to use somethingg like `select count(some_field) as field1` @Bohemian

Comment: @AmrithKrishna why? what are you trying to do? Or do you want the max row for each value in another column?

Answer (score 0):

I am not well-versed in mysql but in SQL server You could do it like this..

```
SELECT 
  * from 
table A
where col1=(select max(col1) from table B where A.id=B.id)
```

---

for Count, you could do

```
SELECT 
    col1
    , col2  from 
    table A
group by 
col1
, col2
Having count(*)>1
```