# How do I show all results where the GROUP BY count is greater than 1 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

Here's my MySQL query and what it returns:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num  
FROM collectors_users
WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
AND lastLogin IS NULL    
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY dateadded DESC;
```

[image]

I only want to return results where num > 1. I tried to change my query like this but it doesn't work saying that `num` is not a recognized column:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num  
FROM collectors_users
WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
AND lastLogin IS NULL
AND num > 1
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY dateadded DESC;
```

How can I return results where num > 1?

Comment: Use `HAVING`, not `WHERE` to limit on the results of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the GROUP BY clause, and before the ORDER BY clause add this:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The `HAVING` clause gets applied nearly last in the execution plan, after all of the rows have been prepared, prior to the `LIMIT` clause. This is most useful for conditions that can't be checked while rows are being accessed, but only after the rows have been accessed, such as an aggregate function like a COUNT(*), though it can be used for non-aggregates.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I should use `HAVING` instead of just posting a modified query. Appreciate it.

Comment: @EthanAllen: I think it's easier for you if I just highlight the change you need to make, as opposed to posting your whole query with one line added, with a comment that says "Try (finding what I changed in) this:"

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` clause. Or another way:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num  
  FROM collectors_users
  WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
  AND lastLogin IS NULL    
  GROUP BY email
  ORDER BY dateadded DESC;
  ) T
WHERE num>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num  
FROM collectors_users
WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
AND lastLogin IS NULL
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY dateadded DESC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

this question can help you to understand why `HAVING` and not `WHERE`

[WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) as num  
FROM collectors_users
WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
AND lastLogin IS NULL
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Having clause.

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS num  
FROM collectors_users
WHERE subscribed != 'NO'
AND lastLogin IS NULL
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY dateadded DESC;
```

for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp