# How to add more conditions with MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
`loanac`.`id`, 
`loanac`.`name`, 
`loanac`.`lacc`, 
SUM(`loantrans`.`in`) as totalin, 
SUM(`loantrans`.`out`) as totalout

FROM loanac, loantrans
WHERE `loanac`.`lacc`=`loantrans`.`account`
GROUP BY `loanac`.`lacc`
```

Here is my query above which is working fine to show all accounts, **BUT** I need to find accounts where SUM(out) > SUM (in) **instead of all accounts**

I've tried to add condition using AND but its showing error, can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WHERE vs HAVING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do criteria on aggregate functions (like SUM or COUNT) is HAVING, not WHERE

```
SELECT loanac.id, loanac.name, loanac.lacc, loanac.phone, 
       SUM(loantrans.in) as totalin, SUM(loantrans.out) as totalout 
FROM loanac, 
     loantrans 
WHERE loanac.lacc=loantrans.account 
GROUP BY loanac.lacc
HAVING SUM(loantrans.out) > SUM(loantrans.in)
```

Comment: Glad you tried to help, your query returning only 3 results but there should be more than 300 results! Any idea how to solve now?

Comment: Try grouping by all non-aggregate columns

Comment: From my view, I can only group by loanac.lacc  or loantrans.account , but both returning same result :(

Comment: Without having access to your data, I can't answer why you're getting a different number of records than you expect. In SQL you must group by any non-aggregate column, and the fact that you aren't is confusing to me. Nevertheless, using the Having clause is correct.

Comment: Scott, here is the db uploaded for you, will you please take a look?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o0ro7r23ztnpfky/AABrfLYUB5DUk-FRvPegHZF_a

Comment: @Machine, the answer to "some number > Null" is false.  Replace NULL in the loantrans.in and loantrans.out data with 0 to get the results you want.  Alternatively, use a function to replace null with 0 in your query.  Only accounts 440, 974, and 952 have non-null deposit totals.

Comment: Bro I'm messed up with "BETWEEN" and "NOT BETWEEN", Will you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026668/how-to-use-opposite-of-between-in-a-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment40768728_26026668

Comment: I'm still stuck :( . SCREENSHOT: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lgmop3zxqaf9mjy/AAAWVWjZXd8da9KDDOqz2ANla?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Try using having

```
SELECT loanac.id, 
loanac.name, 
loanac.lacc, 
loanac.phone, 
SUM(loantrans.in) as totalin, 
SUM(loantrans.out) as totalout 
FROM loanac, loantrans 
WHERE loanac.lacc=loantrans.account 
GROUP BY loanac.lacc 
HAVING SUM(out) > SUM (in)
```

Comment: A little description and proper formatting your answer can bring a good reputation but without this you will miss these points

Comment: Glad you tried to help, your query returning only 3 results but there should be more than 300 results! Any idea how to solve now?