# Join Alias and Where in SQL

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, alias

I am trying to run a query where i can use an alias in where clause

For example:

```
Select V.Fees - Coalesce(V.Payment,0) - Coalesce (V.Adjustment,0) AS Balance
[
the inner join query for the tables
]
Where A.Order not Null and Balance = 0
Order by Name
```

but as usual it is not able to recognize Balance under where?

How can we fix this?

Comment: Use a subquery or repeat the expression or in MySQL use a having clause.

Comment: Or just repeat the operation in the where : `Where A.Order not Null and V.Fees - Coalesce(V.Payment,0) - Coalesce (V.Adjustment,0) = 0`

Comment: having is probably the best bet : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you're asking is to put that field in a CTE and reference it through a join of the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

you can repeat the expression in the where clause

```
Select V.Fees - Coalesce(V.Payment,0) - Coalesce (V.Adjustment,0) AS Balance
[
the inner join query for the tables
]
Where A.Order not Null and (V.Fees - Coalesce(V.Payment,0) - Coalesce (V.Adjustment,0)) = 0
Order by Name
```

Comment: @soumyasubhraKonar, you can accept the answer if it works for you