# MYSQL: filtering via HAVING in some case does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in a MYSQL query ran from a php script.

In my sql statement I need to filter all the users that are too far away so:

```
SELECT
...
ROUND(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($Lat)) *
    SIN(RADIANS(s.Latitude)) + 
    COS(RADIANS($Lat)) *
    COS(RADIANS(s.Latitude)) * 
    COS(RADIANS(s.Longitude) - 
    RADIANS($Lon))) * $unitKm, 2) AS "Distance"
...
HAVING "Distance" <= $Dis
```

Now, there's a user that is 440.55 Km away but, if I pass 334 as "Dis", it's not filtered.

333 is ok, but when bigger than 333, the HAVING clause does not work.

I pass *$Dis* as a number and get it from php via a:

```
$Dis = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'Dis');
```

How could I solve the problem ?

Comment: You probably need to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2905312/1864610

Comment: Thanks, tried but does not solve the problem. But I'll read the link, for sure I'll learn something.

Comment: Presumably, there is an issue with your distance calculation or with the variables used to define it.  The `having` clause is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "Distance" that is a string; you need to use backtics `Distance` in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm using backtics in all the php files beside this one, always thinking "I'll replace them...".