# Selecting with the HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I wrote a quick query

```
select dno from Employee having max(salary)
```

In my table, the maximum salary in 96000 and is associated with dno 8. But for some reason, that select statement gives dno 6.

http://hastebin.com/wewahiloki.vhdl

I feel like this is really obvious but I can't figure it out.

Comment: in this way you get the firts result from query ... having don't work properly without group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having don't work properly without group by 
If you want all the dno with max salary you can use this

```
select dno from Employee  where salary = (select max(salary) from Employee);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you one to get the "dno" that have the highest salary you can use the following query:

```
SELECT dno from employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1
```

The reason is that "having" is used when your are using aggregation operations. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2905312/1641558