# using SUM in whereraw/where in laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have columns named as `PlanCost` `Discount` `AmountPaid` and a label which contains the `Due`

Here,I am trying to display only the rows where the `PlanCost != AmountPaid`

this is my whole query

```
 $getID = isset($inputArray['id']) ? $inputArray['id'] : 0;
    $query = TelePlanSelect::join('tele_plan', 'tele_plan.id', '=', 'tele_plan_select.teleplan_id'  )
        ->leftjoin('tele_payment_defs', 'tele_payment_defs.telereg_id', '=', 'tele_plan_select.telereg_id')
        ->leftjoin('tele_payment_items', function ($join){
            $join->on('tele_payment_items.telepaymentdefs_id', '=', 'tele_payment_defs.id')
                ->on('tele_payment_items.teleplan_id', '=' ,'tele_plan.id');
        } )

        ->selectRaw('tele_plan.id as `PlanID`,' .
            'tele_plan.plan_name as `PlanName`,' .
            'tele_plan.plan_cost as `PlanCost`,' .
            'tele_plan.plan_details as `PlanDetails`,'.
            'sum(tele_payment_items.amount) as  `AmountPaid` ,'.
            'COALESCE(sum(tele_payment_items.discount),0) as `Discount`,'.
            '(COALESCE(tele_plan.plan_cost,0) -  sum(COALESCE(tele_payment_items.discount,0))) - sum(coalesce(tele_payment_items.amount, 0)) as  `Due` '

        )
        ->where('tele_plan_select.telereg_id', $getID)
        ->groupBy('tele_plan.id')
      ->where(' tele_plan.plan_cost', '!=', 'sum(tele_payment_items.amount)');
```

I am not sure whether we can use `sum` in `where/whereraw`
Could someone help me?

EDIT 1 :
`{"message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select tele_plan.id as`PlanID`,tele_plan.plan_name as`PlanName`,tele_plan.plan_cost as`PlanCost`,tele_plan.plan_details as`PlanDetails`,sum(tele_payment_items.amount) as`AmountPaid`,COALESCE(sum(tele_payment_items.discount),0) as`Discount`,(COALESCE(tele_plan.plan_cost,0) -  sum(COALESCE(tele_payment_items.discount,0))) - sum(coalesce(tele_payment_items.amount, 0)) as`Due`from`tele_plan_select`inner join`tele_plan`on`tele_plan`.`id`=`tele_plan_select`.`teleplan_id`left join`tele_payment_defs`on`tele_payment_defs`.`telereg_id`=`tele_plan_select`.`telereg_id`left join`tele_payment_items`on`tele_payment_items`.`telepaymentdefs_id`=`tele_payment_defs`.`id`and`tele_payment_items`.`teleplan_id`=`tele_plan`.`id`where`tele_plan_select`.`telereg_id`= 8 and tele_plan.plan_cost <> sum(tele_payment_items.amount) group by`tele_plan`.`id`) as a) @ C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\halframework\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:625","status":"failed"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw sql functions like `sum`, but you have to wrap them in laravel's [`\DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_raw) function so they won't be escaped.

For your `Where` clause, you should do the following

```
->where('tele_plan.plan_cost', '<>', \DB::raw('sum(tele_payment_items.amount)'));
```

You could also use laravel's [`WhereRaw`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw) function to write your own conditions:

```
->whereRaw('tele_plan.plan_cost <> sum(tele_payment_items.amount)')
```

**Update:**
The error stated that there was a problem with the GroupBy. The reason for this is because a sum can only be done after a group by, but a where can't. So, this will have to be added in a [HAVING clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having).

Replace the where by a having, and this should work:

```
->havingRaw('tele_plan.plan_cost <> sum(tele_payment_items.amount)');
```

Comment: This doesn't work,what I have to know is can we use `sum` inside the where clause in laravel?

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried both examples in my answer? If so, could you update your question and add the output you get and the output you expect?

Comment: I have added the error message and I have written in my Question. I need the rows where the `plan_cost != tele_payment_items.amout`