# How to filter records based on no of their occurrence in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a table Employer with fields EmployerID and EmployeeID. I need to print all the employeers with more than 2 employees ie count(EmployerID) > 2 when grouped by EmployerID . I am so far able to count the occurrence but not able to filter based on given condition.

select EmployerID ,count(EmployerID) from Employer group by EmployerID

Comment: Add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2` clause after your `GROUP BY` statement. So it would be:

SELECT EmployerID , COUNT(EmployerID) 
   FROM Employer 
   GROUP BY EmployerID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2905335/2829487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployerID,COUNT(EmployeeID)
FROM EMPLOYER
GROUP BY EmployerID
HAVING COUNT(EmployeeID) > 2
```