# Eloquent : query whereHas model count greater than

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got the following:

- User, Role, with a role_user pivot table and a belongsToMany
  relationship
- User, Location, with a location_user pivot table and a belongsToMany 
  relationship

There's 2 roles for the user: owner & worker

Location has a 'workers_max' field

I try to build a query to get All locations where 'workers_max' is greater than number of associated workers.

I tried:

```
Locations::withCount('workers')->where('workers_max', '>', 'workers_count')->get();
```

but it returns all the locations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the query using Laravel Query Logging, you will notice the `withCount()` is using `where` to query the result. If you want to filter on aggregates, you need to use `having`.

Just a little change to your query, you should be able to get what you want.

[See how to use `havingRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

[Difference between `where` and `having`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It seems the result of `withCount()` cannot be used in a where clause because it's an aggregate function. I think you will have to use Join.

If you don't want to join, you can do something VERY BAD. Load all of them, `workers_count` will be available for you, then filter the collection like this

```
$locations = Locations::withCount('workers')->get();
$goodLocations = $locations->filter(function($location, $key){
    return $location->workers_max > $location->workers_count;
});
```

As I said, not the best solution, but I think this can get the job done, as long as the collection is not huge.

For efficiency, you will have to use Join

Comment: Thanks, i did simplified a bit since i have shortcuts: Location::withCount('workers')->where('users_max', '>', 2)->get() is working but Location::withCount('workers')->where('users_max', '>', 'workers_count') is NOT :(

Comment: Oh ok. Good. Sorry I couldn't give you the exact query you wanted. Did not know about your shortcuts. BTW, is your field 'users_max' or 'worker_max'. Bit of confusion here.

Comment: No what i mean is that withCount is good starting point but the comparison with workers_count is not working : it returns all the locations..

Comment: Oh sorry. I see now. Let me have another look

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and i already learned a lot. But as you say i would prefer to use join, to perform a single scopeQuery. Just don't understand how to do so !