# Hard to explain, new at mysql

Tags: mysql

Calculate **each** supplier's total sales quantity and get the sales person's name if the sales person supplies parts more than 1000 units in total.

Table info:

Supplier {s_num, s_name, status, city}

Spj {s_num, p_num, j_num, qty}

This is what I have:

```
SELECT s_name, SUM(qty) AS sum
FROM Supplier, Spj
WHERE Supplier.s_num = Spj.s_num
AND qty > 1000
GROUP BY s_name;
```

I think my error is in this line:

```
AND qty > 1000
```

maybe I am using the "GROUP BY" incorrectly...

No suppliers quantity is above 800, so I get a blank result.

I want to test this:

```
"sum of quantity for each supplier" > 1000
```

Comment: Replace `AND qty > 1000 GROUP BY s_name` with `GROUP BY s_name HAVING(qty > 1000)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE vs HAVING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Comment: Query error with ambiguous column name in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HAVING to access aggregate results after a group by clause:

```
SELECT s_name, SUM(qty) AS sum
FROM Supplier, Spj
WHERE Supplier.s_num = Spj.s_num
GROUP BY s_name
HAVING qty > 1000;
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having) for more info on having vs where.