# List all employees having percentage greater than some number

Tags: mysql, sql

How to list all employees having percentage greater than some number,
and percentage gets calculated on the basis of max salary.

**Example:**

> if max salary is 100 and an employee salary is 50 then percentage
>   should show 50.

This is what i tried:

```
select (salary/Max(salary)*100) as percentage from test.employeetable
where percentage > 75;
```

[image: Table]

Error that i get is:

> Unknown column 'percentage' in 'where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the max in a variable, then select the relevant results

```
select @max := max(salary) from test.employeetable;
select (salary/@max*100) as pc from test.employeetable having pc > 75;
```

note the [`having`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having) instead of `where`.

You could display the relevant salary (etc...) as well

```
select @max := max(salary) from test.employeetable;
select salary,(salary/@max*100) as pc from test.employeetable having pc > 75;
```

Without using a variable

```
select (salary/m.mx*100) as pc from test.employeetable, 
(select max(salary) as mx from test.employeetable) as m
having pc > 75;
```

Comment: is it necessary to store value in variable, this works though

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that;

```
select * from (
select (salary / (select max(salary) from test.employeetable) * 100) as percentage from test.employeetable) Records
where percentage > 75;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (salary/Max(salary)*100) as percentage 
from test.employeetable 
where (salary/Max(salary)*100) > 75;
```

in MySql you Can not use an "as" in where clause

Comment: Error: Invalid use of group function

Comment: Sorry i have not seen the "max"

Answer (score -1):

Use a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT (salary / MAX(salary) * 100) AS percentage
  FROM test.employeetable
) x
WHERE percentage > 75
```

Comment: getting percentage of first salary only.