# Laravel Database filter total greater than n

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How can I filter out only results when total is greater than n?
other words only IPs with more wisits than n (say 500)

I tried `->where('total','>',500)` but it didn't work

Thank you

```
$visits = DB::table('visits')
    ->select('ip_address',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->where('timestamp', '>=',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
    ->groupBy('ip_address')
    ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WHERE` cannot be used on grouped item (such as `count(*)`) whereas  `HAVING` can.
You can refer [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2905312/1545385) question to understand more details,

You have to use `having`

```
->having('total', '>', 100)
```

optionally in your case you can use havingRaw

```
->havingRaw('count(*) > 2500')
->havingRaw('total > 2500')
```

ref : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: Unfortunately  ```Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'total' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: select `ip_address`, count(*) as total from `visits` where `timestamp` >= 2018-02-28 00:00:00 group by `ip_address` having `total` > 100 order by `total` desc)","code":"42000","status_code":500,"debug":```

Comment: havingRaw is  great for scenarios where you comparing one field to another summed since the sum result can be a text and interfere with the comparision.

Comment: @Vojta for your case make sure to add each field in your select query to the group by function.