# php/mysql query not working

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

my sql query is :

```
SELECT
    wp_news_contents.*,
    (SUM(IF(sumset,1,0))/(COUNT(wp_news_tags.tag_id) +2)) AS jaccard,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('wp_news_tags.tag_id=',tag_id SEPARATOR ' || ')
        FROM wp_news_tags
        WHERE content_id = 1
    ) AS sumset
FROM wp_news_contents, wp_news_tags
WHERE wp_news_contents.id = wp_news_tags.content_id
AND wp_news_tags.content_id != '1'
AND jaccard > 0.5
GROUP BY wp_news_contents.id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

but query not working and show error :

> jaccard columns not defined

what is wrong & how to solve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Answer (score 0):

you can't add any other fields after the 'select *', you can use the '*' without any other fields or just list all the fields you want without '*'. try replace the '*' with all the specific fields you want.

Comment: sorry I use the empty '', I mean the star character in it

Comment: jaccard is not a real field. jaccard is (SUM(IF(sumset,1,0))/(COUNT(wp_news_tags.tag_id) +2)) ?