# Query specific text inside json text data in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I'd like to query from the `reviewed_by` table below where the "company" is "AAA" and "review" is "Need Review"
Here's mysql table :

```
+-----------+
| DATA_TYPE |
+-----------+
| text      |
+-----------+

+-------------------------+
| reviewed_by             |
+-------------------------+
|[{"company":"AAA","review":"OK","reviewed_at":"2021-01-26 08:59:26"}]|
|[{"company":"BBB","review":"OK","reviewed_at":"2021-01-26 08:59:26"}]|
|[{"company":"AAA","review":"Need Review","reviewed_at":"N\/A"}]|
+-------------------------+
```

Here's the #1 query i've tried :

```
SELECT * FROM `t_transaction` 
WHERE `reviewed_by` 
LIKE '%`"company":"AAA","review":"Need Review"`%'
```

Here's the #2 query i've tried :

```
SELECT * FROM `t_transaction` 
WHERE `reviewed_by` 
LIKE '%"company":"AAA","review":"Need Review"%'
```

ci3 query :

```
$like = ['reviewed_by','"company":"AAA","review":"Need Review"'];
$this->db->select('*')   
         ->from('t_transacion')
         ->group_by('id')
         ->like($like[0],$like[1]);
```

The result i've got from those 2 queries was nothing,
How can i do this type of query (and also if using codeigniter 3) ?

Comment: #2 (without the backticks) should work. If it doesn't, it's likely not the `LIKE`...

Comment: @Benni do you mean by Query #2 above ? already tried it and got nothing

Comment: I tested the exact query (in plain MySql, not codeigniter), and it worked fine

Comment: MySQL can query inside JSON text, for example:

```SELECT * FROM 't_transaction' 
WHERE reviewed_by->>'$.company' = 'AAA' AND 
reviewed_by->>'$.review' = 'Need Review';```

Comment: If you have any control over the database design, don't store JSON under a single column, rather make all those JSON keys a separate column. It will make your searches not only easier, but much more efficient too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql has some functions that allow you to do search over a `json` field. [See documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html).

The `reviewed_by` column is a json array and you want to seach the first element of that array. Using the function [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) you can extract data from the json field. In your case to get the json in the first position in the array so we execute `JSON_EXTRACT(reviewed_by, '$[0]')` which will return `{"company":"...","review":"..","reviewed_at":"..."}`. From the returned json we can call again the `JSON_EXTRACT` function to get a value given a key. If we select `JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(reviewed_by, '$[0]'), "$.company")` this will return the company value from inside the json.

There are different ways to select what you want. I will give you two option and they have pros and cons. Take a look at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having/18710763#18710763).

First approach using the where clause:

```
SELECT reviewed_by
FROM t_transaction
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(reviewed_by, '$[0]'), "$.company") = "AAA"
  AND JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(reviewed_by, '$[0]'), "$.review") = "Need Review";
```

Second approach using the having clause:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(reviewed_by, '$[0]') AS json
FROM t_transaction
HAVING json -> "$.company" = "AAA"
   AND json -> "$.review" = "Need Review";
```