# How do I use WHERE on Computed Column?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get some queries written for some integrity across two tables. The query is something like this

```
SELECT if( o.is_discounted !=1, o.item_cost, o.discounted_item_cost ) AS order_item_total,
SUM( oi.quantity * oi.price ) AS item_total
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
WHERE order_item_total != item_total
GROUP BY o.id
```

I've definitely used aliases to such columns in the past so I'm not sure why in this case it's telling me `order_item_total` is not a column.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error  [from mySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html): Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Comment: Try replacing `WHERE` with `HAVING`, that should fix it.

Comment: @xQbert You are correct, but the answer this isn't as nice as the one here, as far as this specific query goes. It's funny I've never tried this before - I thought had. But apparently it was just in ORDER BY and HAVING clauses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use having on aggregated columns.

```
SELECT if(o.is_discounted != 1, o.item_cost, o.discounted_item_cost) order_item_total,
  SUM(oi.quantity * oi.price) item_total
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING order_item_total != item_total
```

Comment: close having & group by are backwards.

Comment: Yup. This is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

try wrapping the whole thing in another `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT if( o.is_discounted !=1, o.item_cost, o.discounted_item_cost ) AS order_item_total,
    SUM( oi.quantity * oi.price ) AS item_total
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
    GROUP BY o.id
) x
WHERE X.order_item_total != X.item_total
```

Comment: This one actually works off the bat but waiting to mark as answer to see if there's one without "fake" subquery

Comment: @DaveStein There are probably better ways of doing this.  This is def a quick and dirty way to get the job done

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE` comes before `SELECT` when manipulating data.
So you need `WHERE if( o.is_discounted !=1, o.item_cost, o.discounted_item_cost ) != SUM( oi.quantity * oi.price )`

The other way to handle this is use a subquery

```
SELECT 
  ..
 FROM 
   ( //your query here
   ) t
//now you can use your aliases
WHERE t.order_item_total != t.item_total
```

Here with the having:

```
SELECT if( o.is_discounted !=1, o.item_cost, o.discounted_item_cost ) AS order_item_total,
SUM( oi.quantity * oi.price ) AS item_total
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING order_item_total != item_total
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and then it told me "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @DaveStein - Just noticed you are using a GROUP BY clauses, just change the WHERE to a HAVING statement and it should work for you.

Comment: `where X != sum()` ? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @MostyMostacho did you read my comment???  I didn't realize he was using a group by so I mentioned to change it using the HAVING clause or just wrap it in a sub query.

Comment: @JonH it doesn't know about `o.is_discounted` when I added `HAVING` after the GROUP BY

Comment: @DaveStein can you wrap it all in a subquery and then reference the aliases?

Comment: @MostyMostacho yeah i keep all the summed data in the order table, so sum of items, taxes, shipping, etc.. I am writing this to double check that it matches my actual order items table.

Comment: @JonH that is the answer below which I also commented on