# Getting a MySQL column whose name isn't defined in my table

Tags: mysql, format, row

I am trying to write a query which is hypothetical at this point that would look something like this:

```
SELECT customers.*, 
       customers_cars.car
        (SELECT main_vehicle 
         FROM customers 
         WHERE customer='Joe') 
FROM customers 
WHERE type='CoolCustomer';
```

My table actually has values like car1, car2, car3 and I'd like to have those values "formatted" on runtime. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: so what is the error you are getting

Comment: coulld  you pl take a look at this segment customers_cars.car(SELECT main_vehicle FROM customers WHERE customer='Joe')  and correct the err

Comment: That is not valid syntax in any flavor of SQL that I'm aware of.

Comment: And "just doesn't work" is not a built-in error message in any RDBMS.

Comment: @Jack Maney: there is a special newbies edition that literally outputs "I don't work" I suppose

Comment: You can practice query logic at http://sqlzoo.net , it has sample data. You can also practice at http://sqlfiddle.com , it has no sample data however. SqlFiddle is the bee's knees. Its Text to DDL is very cool, accepts virtually all kind of table format; it can even run multiple statements in one go,   you can see the each result neatly segregated; of which for example pgAdmin(Postgresql admin tool) cannot, pgAdmin can only output the result of the first query of multiple queries, succeeding queries doesn't appear on grid

Comment: @MichaelBuen thanks for the sql links, i hadn't known about this, will check them out...

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown us the schema of your table; that makes it harder than it might be to help you.

If you are seeking to get `car1` column or `car2` column or ... then there are at least two problems:

1. Your table is incorrectly designed.
2. You cannot build up the name of a column (or table) as part of the query.

You should put the information about each of a customer's cars in a separate table from the information about the customer.  Thus, the information that the customer's name is 'Joe' belongs in one table; the fact that he drives a Lamborghini should be recorded in a separate table.  There might be multiple records in the table of cars for each customer.

You'd also need to join the two tables; your syntactically incorrect query doesn't attempt to do that.

---

You have two tables with columns:

- **Customers**: customer, type, ...
- **Customers_Cars**: main_vehicle, car1, car2, car3

You probably have, but haven't shown, some sort of 'customer' column in `Customers_Cars`.  In fact, you should probably have a 'Customer ID' column in each table.  Further, the `Customers_Cars` table should be just:

- **Customers_Cars**: CustomerID, CarNum, CarInfo, MainVehicle

In this, I'm assuming `MainVehicle` is a boolean flag, and that there is one entry tagged true per customer.

Your SELECT statement then becomes:

```
SELECT U.*, 
       C.CarInfo
  FROM Customers      AS U
  JOIN Customers_Cars AS C ON C.CustomerID = U.CustomerID
 WHERE C.MainVehicle = TRUE
   AND U.Customer = 'Joe'
   AND U.Type     = 'CoolCustomer';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are referring to giving columns alias names. Please see this reference on use of aliases: [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

But the bottom line with aliases is to use the `AS` keyword. You may require an alias when you use a subquery as you are doing here with the query in parentheses.

In your example, try the following:

```
SELECT customers.*, car1 AS customers_cars.car
   (SELECT car2 AS main_vehicle 
     FROM customers 
     WHERE customer='Joe') 
FROM customers 
WHERE type='CoolCustomer';
```

Comment: @JackManey is this referencing ok?