# mysql using calculated column at where/having

Tags: mysql, select, alias, where-clause, having

i have an question how to use an "alias" column at the where/having clause. I know there are some question with an related topic. But I search trough the web and on stackoverfolw and doesn't find an solution.

So i hope for help at this way..

The following statement works well:

```
SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(*) AS A 
    FROM my_statistics 
    WHERE TIMESTAMP>NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY
    GROUP BY PHRASE ORDER BY A DESC 
    LIMIT 16;
```

`PHRASE` and `TIMESTAMP`are columns at the table. 
The code selects the top 16 PHRASES, which are inserts by users on the last 7 days.
There are also exist an column USER and so i like now to select the top 16 phrases which are inserted by more than one user.
So i tried this:

```
SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(*) AS A, COUNT(DISTINCT(USER)) AS B
    FROM my_statistics
    WHERE TIMESTAMP>NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY
          AND B>1
    GROUP BY PHRASE ORDER BY A DESC 
    LIMIT 16;
```

On other questions on stackoverflow i fond the info, that i have to use `HAVING`

```
SELECT PHRASE,COUNT(*) AS A, COUNT(DISTINCT(USER)) AS B
    FROM my_statistics
    WHERE TIMESTAMP>NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY      
    GROUP BY PHRASE ORDER BY A DESC 
    HAVING B>1
    LIMIT 16;
```

But this returns an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING B>1
>       LIMIT 16' at line 5

I have no idea, how the right syntax could be.
Hope for any kind of help here.
Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error

Comment: @Sammaye reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error ...does it men, it's not possible?

Comment: Alias colums are not supported, yes; according to the docs for WHERE

Comment: @Sammaye is there a way to solve that without an alias column? i read a lot about using `having`for that...

Comment: it is possible.. see the answer from @Romil

Comment: Yea I think having can have it but I am not sure about with the Limit, have you tried @Romil's Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `ORDER BY A DESC`  after `Having` clause.

```
SELECT phrase, 
       Count(*)                AS A, 
       Count(DISTINCT( user )) AS B 
FROM   my_statistics 
WHERE  timestamp > Now() - INTERVAL 7 day 
GROUP  BY phrase 
HAVING b > 1 
ORDER  BY a DESC 
LIMIT  16;
```

Comment: splitting group by and order by.. that's it!! i always used both together!! thank you!