# MySQL HAVING not behaving properly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, having

I have a query:

```
SELECT I.Id
    , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(I.StatusId ORDER BY I.TransactionId DESC), ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS StatusId
    , SUM(I.RefundAmount) AS RefundAmount
    FROM (
        SELECT I.Id
            , IT.Id AS TransactionId
            , IT.StatusId
            , IF(IT.TypeId = 2, IT.RefundAmount, 0) AS RefundAmount
            FROM Items I
            INNER JOIN ItemTransactions IT ON IT.ItemId = I.Id
            WHERE I.Id = someValue
    ) I
    GROUP BY I.Id
    HAVING StatusId = 1 AND RefundAmount = 0
```

Where `Items` table has transaction records stored in `ItemTransactions` table. I've been using this type of query and works for me until this time, got some issues with the `having` clause.

The query works in `SQL Editors` but not working properly when used on `stored procedures`. (Don't get me wrong, I've been using this query for most of my `stored procedures`). Debugging line per line, found that there is an issue with `having` clause.

As a temporary fix, I changed the query to:

```
SELECT I.Id
    , I.StatusId
    , I.RefundAmount
    FROM (
        SELECT I.Id
            , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(I.StatusId ORDER BY I.TransactionId DESC), ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS StatusId
            , SUM(I.RefundAmount) AS RefundAmount
            FROM (
                SELECT I.Id
                    , IT.Id AS TransactionId
                    , IT.StatusId
                    , IF(IT.TypeId = 2, IT.RefundAmount, 0) AS RefundAmount
                    FROM Items I
                    INNER JOIN ItemTransactions IT ON IT.ItemId = I.Id
                    WHERE I.Id = someValue
            ) I
            GROUP BY I.Id
            --HAVING StatusId = 1 AND RefundAmount = 0
    ) I
    WHERE I.StatusId = 1 AND I.RefundAmount = 0
```

The query works fine. But I'd like to know if somebody has already encountered this, and found a fix. I'm using `MySQL 5.0`.

Thanks

Comment: I was having the same perplexity, and then realized that earlier in the procedure I DECLARE'd variables with the same names as ones in the HAVING clause. Renaming the former fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` clause is used to filter data on the common attributes and expressions. `HAVING` clause is used to filter data after groupping had been performed and it's arguments should be either the ones of the `GROUP BY` clause, or expressions containing aggregate functions.
It is also illegal to use the alias of the column in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses, while it does works for the `ORDER BY` clause.

One option, as you've found, is to use a sub-query and then column references will work.
Another one is to duplicate the whole expression in the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT I.Id,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(I.StatusId ORDER BY I.TransactionId DESC),
           ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS StatusId,
    SUM(I.RefundAmount) AS RefundAmount
    FROM (
        SELECT I.Id
            , IT.Id AS TransactionId
            , IT.StatusId
            , IF(IT.TypeId = 2, IT.RefundAmount, 0) AS RefundAmount
            FROM Items I
            INNER JOIN ItemTransactions IT ON IT.ItemId = I.Id
            WHERE I.Id = someValue
    ) I
    GROUP BY I.Id
    HAVING
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(I.StatusId ORDER BY I.TransactionId DESC),
         ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) = 1
    AND SUM(I.RefundAmount) = 0;
```

---

**EDIT:** A closer look leaded to this question [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error) and to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html), that outlines that it is possible to use column aliases in `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses if such aliases are quoted with backticks, like:

```sql
...
HAVING `StatusId` = 1 AND `RefundAmount` = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm familiar with `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses, but not with expressions. I've been using column's alias in `HAVING` clauses, seems to work for me, until this time. Is this a flaw?

Comment: Added backticks but didn't work. But the link you've posted is great. Anyway, I was able to make the `HAVING` clause working, just by making the `ALIAS` name different from the field name. It worked.

Comment: @KaeL, What's the MySQL version you are using?

Comment: @Pacerier: Perhaps I was using version 5. I can't remember, this was less than 3 years ago. :D