# Order by a value returned from function called in Stored Procedure MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I want to order by dist : **dist** is a double value returned from function called **isNeighbour** It throws error as dist is undefined : Unknown column 'dist' in field list

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `connectarabs`.`maxEdges` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `maxEdges`(id int,lat double,lon double,rad double)
BEGIN


if lat is null then

set lat=(select a.latitude from account a where a.id=id);
end if;
if lon is null then
set lon=(select a.longitude from account a where a.id=id);
end if;
 SELECT friends.* FROM account friends left  join account_friendTest me on (friends.id=me.second_account)
  or (friends.id=me.first_account) where (me.first_account=id OR me.second_account=id) AND friends.id <> id AND
     (   ((select isNeighbour(lat,lon,friends.latitude,friends.longitude,rad) as dist )<rad)   ) order by dist;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't alias column used in `WHERE` clause and use that in `ORDER BY` clause. Instead you need to `SELECT` that column and use `HAVING` clause to filter it:

```
SELECT friends.*,
       isNeighbour(lat,lon,friends.latitude,friends.longitude,rad) AS dist
FROM account friends
     LEFT JOIN account_friendTest me
        ON (friends.id=me.second_account)
           OR (friends.id=me.first_account)
WHERE (me.first_account=id OR me.second_account=id) AND
      friends.id <> id
HAVING dist < rad
ORDER BY dist;
```

Comment: Yes,That is working Perfectly Thanks very Much but why I have to put Having dist<rad why I can't simply place: where.. ... AND dist<rad

Comment: I have shifted that condition from `WHERE` clause to `HAVING` clause. If you put this condition in `WHERE` clause also, then it has to do the function computation twice, which would reduce the performance of query.

Comment: No, It throws error I searched now and I found check it's very Interested [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)