# sql/mysql filter including only the max value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a resultset that is like this:

```
ID | name  | myvalue
 1 | A1    | 22
 2 | A2    | 22
 3 | A3    | 21
 4 | A4    | 33
 5 | A5    | 33
 6 | A6    | 10
 7 | A7    | 10
 8 | A8    | 10
 9 | A9    | 5
```

what i want, is to include only rows that contains the highest "myvalue" available (in the previous example is 33), then:

```
ID | name  | myvalue
 4 | A4    | 33
 5 | A5    | 33
```

IE the query should pick the highest "myvalue" available (IE 33) and it should remove the rows that have myvalue < 33

```
SELECT ..... WHERE myvalue = THE_HIGHEST_OF(myvalue)
```

Hoping to have been clear...

thank you in advance

---

edit:

my current query is

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (very long code that returns a integer as relevance score) AS myvalue
FROM
    mytable
HAVING
    myvalue = ?????
ORDER BY
    myvalue DESC
```

now the highest myvalue can be 10, 20, 30, any number... in the final resultset i want to include only the rows that have the highest possible relevance score

ive tried using GROUP BY, but i always need to repeat the...

```
    (very long code that returns a integer as relevance score) AS myvalue
```

...twice

Comment: thank you for your answers, is there a way to do this with one single select?

Comment: What do you exactly want? (want to repeat `myvalue` twice or once?)

Comment: Can't you select `MAX` from your *very long code...*?

Comment: i think not, but i'm not sure, how i shoud use group by?

Comment: See [how to use `GROUP BY` clause in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16232/discussion-between-hims056-and-topeerornottopeer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE myValue IN (SELECT max(myValue) From t);
```

###[*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6135ad/1)

Edit:

As per [discussion with OP.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16232/discussion-between-hims056-and-topeerornottopeer)
OP wants to use *alias* in `WHERE` clause. But you can only use column aliases in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.
Look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error/942592#942592)

Answer (score 5):

try this,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   myValue = (SELECT max(myValue) From tableName)
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/180ba/1)

thanks to hims056 for the DDL

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer no. you should calculate the max value separately.

Comment: ouch!, myvalue is, actually, a relevance score in a fulltext search, that i want not to repeat twice... maybe it is possible using some custom function? btw thanks you all, +1 to every1

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from mytable a
where my_value = (select max(myvalue) from my_table b 
                  --where  b.name = a.name
                  )
```

(if you use the commented code, will get the maximums per name :) )

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (very long code that returns a integer as relevance score) AS myvalue
FROM
    mytable
HAVING
    myvalue = MAX(myvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is :

```
select * 
from myTable m1 
where not exists (select 1 from myTable where myValue > m1.myValue)
```