# Rank MySQL for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, rows, rank

I would need an help for a task I should implement.
I have a table, in which are included following fields:

1. Username
2. Score
3. Competition

Each username can be present in the table several times, thus he can have several scores.
In any case, a username can be associated to only one country.

Here below an example of my table:

```
Username !! Country || Score
Bob       ! Italy   !   100
Bob       ! Italy   !   150
Christian ! Italy   !   500
Christian ! Italy   !   200
Fred      | Germany |  80
Carl      | Germany |  700
Charlie   | France  |   400
Charlie   | France  |  280
Jean      | France  |   90
```

What I would get is a MYSQL command to get the ranking of each user in his country, considering only his best score and discarding the others.

Therefore, my ideal output should look like:

Christian ranked #1 in Italy
Bob ranked #2 in Italy
Carl ranked #1 in Germany

Fred ranked #2 in Germany

Charlie ranked #1 in France
Jean ranked #2 in France

I can order the users and have their rank, but having all the entries.
What I would like to have is the ranking with just the best scores.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks a lot

Comment: And what have you tried? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: An example would be helpful, however, the max method/function might be useful, 

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE myValue IN (SELECT max(myValue) From t);
`

 Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257378/4612518
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation and window function `rank()`, if you are running MySQL 8.0

```
select 
    username,
    country,
    max(score) top_score,
    rank() over(partition by country order by max(score) desc) country_rank
from mytable
group by username, country
order by country, country_rank
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately I have a lower version of MySQL, so I guess I cannot deal with commands like "partition" because I get an error message. Thanks anyway for giving this hint.

Answer (score 0):

One way that this could be done is:

```
SELECT o1.Username, o1.Country, o1.maxScore, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Username) 
     FROM `scores` s2
     WHERE o1.Country = s2.Country AND s2.Score > o1.maxScore) + 1 AS ranking
FROM (
     SELECT Username, Country, MAX(Score) AS maxScore
     FROM `scores` s1
     GROUP BY Username) o1
```

This works by:

- 1st getting the **max score for each Username** seen at alias ***"o1"*** (`MAX(Score) AS maxScore`)
- 2nd using the maxScore result found above and a subQuery ***"s2"*** to find the rank for each Username and Country

Since `MAX(Score) AS maxScore` is an aggregated result, we cannot use the subQuery directly in 1 query, but first we have to aggregate the results and use the resulted max scores.