# mysql 1111 invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

This query works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT leads.contact_id, count(leads.contact_id) as orders 
FROM leads
WHERE leads.status="sold" 
GROUP BY leads.contact_id
```

But this one doesn't. Why?

```
SELECT leads.contact_id, count(leads.contact_id) as orders
FROM leads
WHERE orders > 1 and leads.status="sold" 
GROUP BY leads.contact_id
```

When executing this query I get the error

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'orders' in 'where clause'

Even when replacing **orders** by **count(leads.contact_id)** it doesn't work:

```
SELECT leads.contact_id, count(leads.contact_id) as orders
FROM leads
WHERE count(leads.contact_id) > 1 and leads.status="sold" 
GROUP BY leads.contact_id
```

Returning following error message:

> ## 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand SQL order of operation, you will know why your query won't work.

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

`WHERE` clause is evaluated before `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  So it won't know what `count(leads.contact_id)` or `orders` is.  `HAVING` on the other than is evaluated after `GROUP BY`.  It is used to filter aggregates.

```
SELECT leads.contact_id, count(leads.contact_id) as orders 
FROM leads
WHERE leads.status="sold" 
GROUP BY leads.contact_id  
HAVING orders > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used **HAVING** instead of **WHERE** because WHERE can only be used for filtering the original data table not the computed one. Yet the column *count(leads.contact_id)* or *orders* is a computed column not an original column of the table therefore I had to use HAVING like this to make it work:

```
SELECT leads.contact_id, count(leads.contact_id) as orders 
FROM leads
WHERE leads.status="sold" 
GROUP BY leads.contact_id  
HAVING orders>1
```

Also see this [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156003/2166778)