# List all column names that are non-unique across tables

Tags: mysql

I have a need to know which column names are used on more than one table of my database.

I've got this query as a start, which gives me a frequency table of column names across the database:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, count(COLUMN_NAME) count
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

However, I'd like the query to also do the following:

1. Limit to only those records where `count>1` (I tried adding `AND count>1` to the `WHERE` clause, but I got the error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'`)
2. Show the names of all the tables on which each column appears (this could entail multiple rows per column name, one for each table name).  If it's easier, I can leave off the `count` column, as long as condition 1 is met.

Note: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193780), but I don't want to search for a specific column; I want to find ALL column names that are repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a need to know which column names are used on more than one
> table of my database

This will give which tables are used more than once

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) >1 ;
```

If you want to know how many the columns are repeated and which one is repeated the most use:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS col_cnt
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) >1 
ORDER BY col_cnt DESC;
```

Edit. I missed the second requirements , so you could use below query to find the table names as well:

```
SELECT i.COLUMN_NAME,
       i.TABLE_NAME,
       col_cnt
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
INNER JOIN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
                   COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS col_cnt
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbname'
            GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
            HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) >1 
             ) AS tbl ON i.COLUMN_NAME=tbl.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY col_cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Brilliant.  [`HAVING`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156003) is the key word I was missing.  This accomplishes my condition 1, and based on this I figured out a query that also satisfies condition 2.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee I missed the second condition, so I added an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ergest Basha's answer I came up with the following query, which meets both conditions (lists the non-unique columns AND shows which tables they appear on):

```
SELECT I.COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, F.freq
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) freq
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
  GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
) F
ON I.COLUMN_NAME=F.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName' 
AND F.freq>1
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
```