# check if two dates are equal in codeigniter with Active Record

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to check if two dates are equal, its `$query_array['datepicker']` and `absensi_tanggal`. They have the different format, so i `CONVERT` the `absensi_tanggal`.

**Do SQL automatically convert the date?** i tried not to convert it, but the query is not working, it always return 0 row.

So i tried this code, but its not working.

```
$q = $this->db->select('*', 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), absensi_tanggal, 101) AS temp')->from('msabsensi')->limit($limit, $offset)
             ->join('msumat', 'msabsensi.umat_id = msumat.umat_id')
             ->join('mskelas', 'mskelas.kelas_id = msumat.kelas_id');

$q->where('CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), absensi_tanggal, 101)', $query_array['datepicker']);
$result['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
```

This is the error i got (i think the `CONVERT AS` that i did in `select()` is not working) :

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(10), absensi_tanggal, 101) '04/01/2013' LIMIT 10' at line 5

SELECT * FROM (`msabsensi`) JOIN `msumat` ON `msabsensi`.`umat_id` = `msumat`.`umat_id` JOIN `mskelas` ON `mskelas`.`kelas_id` = `msumat`.`kelas_id` WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), absensi_tanggal, 101) '04/01/2013' LIMIT 10

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_gabdb\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `temp` is not used as alias of any column in this query and you are referring it in your where clause

```
$this->db->select('*')
->from('msabsensi')->limit($limit, $offset)
->join('msumat', 'msabsensi.umat_id = msumat.umat_id')
->join('mskelas', 'mskelas.kelas_id = msumat.kelas_id')
//->where('temp = '.$query_array['datepicker']) // here
->where('absensi_tanggal = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  "' .$query_array['datepicker'] . '",  \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) ,  \'%Y-%m-%d\' )') 
->get()->num_rows();
```

**Edit**

Check [Problem with alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

[Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in copying the code. Please see my updated question. Your solution is not working, it always return 0 rows. Thanks for your help

Comment: @BlazeTama Sorry for late reply. I just read mysql documentation that we can't use alias in where clause. See edited answer.

Comment: @BlazeTama Try edited query.May it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, i forgot about that part :D 
Thanks for your help, but its still not working..now it seems i have some mistake with the SELECT statement. Please see my updated question, i updated the code. Thanks

Comment: I also updated the error, its a different error

Comment: @BlazeTama Can you give me what kind of data present in `absensi_tanggal` column and `$query_array['datepicker']` with their date format?

Comment: @BlazeTama See edited query. And also you forgot `=` in where clause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29765/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-yogesh-suthar)

Comment: Thank you very much for your huge help, its too bad i can't give more than 1 upvote