# How can I increment a row in a SELECT Statement?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, increment

is it possible to increment last row with a constant value? I would like to receive a response like this:

```
Date        |  Value 
-------------------
2013-11-01  |  14.32
2013-11-02  |  15.32
2013-11-03  |  16.32
...         |  ...
```

I've tried it with Variables:.

```
SET @INCREMENT := '1.00';
SET @VALUE := '14.32';
SELECT `Date`, @VALUE + @INCREMENT
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Date` > '2013-11-01'
```

but this shows only one constant value in row2.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16715618/111794)

Comment: Can you post an example data (www.sqlfiddle.com) so we can see what you mean instead we need to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to reset the value for each row:

```
SET @INCREMENT := '1.00';
SET @VALUE := '14.32';
SELECT `Date`, (@VALUE := @VALUE + @INCREMENT) as value
FROM `table` 
WHERE `Date` > '2013-11-01';
```

Normally when you do this, you would have an `order by` clause to ensure that the rows are returned in the order you want them to be.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's great. Value ist incresing by Increment. I just inserted an @ in line 3: SELECT `Date`, (@VALUE := @VALUE + @INCREMENT) as value

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean this, but this seemed to be the most logical..
Assuming you have an existing table with Date and Value

```
SET @INCREMENT = 1.00;

SELECT
    Date "date"
 , (Value + @INCREMENT) "value"
FROM 
  table 
WHERE
  Date > '2013-11-01'
ORDER BY
  Date ASC
```

Or even better (because you dont need the "overhead" off an user variable to calculate this on runtime)

```
SELECT
    Date "date"
 , (Value + 1.00) "value"
FROM 
  table 
WHERE
  Date > '2013-11-01'
ORDER BY
  Date ASC
```