# Detecting patterns in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Having a table like this:

```
Table: statuses
ID  | status
----|---------
777 | 1
675 | 1
651 | 0
611 | 1
600 | 0
554 | 1
443 | 0
323 | 0
222 | 1
112 | 1
```

How to select only the rows, where two (or more) statuses in the row are 0?
(in the sample case only 443, 323), and group them by the first ID in series.

So the output would be:

```
ID  | status | group
----|--------|---------
443 | 0      | 443
323 | 0      | 443
```

Comment: Can be done programmatically based on what language you wanna use?

Comment: SQL is not the appropriate tool for this purpose. Select all the rows that qualify then filter and group them in the application code.

Comment: how is your data sorted? if there is not another field indicating the order (so you are relying on insertion order) you won't get consistent results. tables are sets, the rows have no intrinsic order unless specified.

Answer (score 2):

If a programmatic approach is not possible, you can try this query (though it will have worse performance).

```
 select
    s.id,
    0 as status,
    group_field.id as group
from 
    statuses s,
    (select id from statuses where status = 0 group by id having count(1) > 1 limit 1) group_field
where 
    s.id in(select id from statuses where id = 0 group by id having count(1) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
id, STATUS,
@st_order:=if(@pre_st!=status,0,@st_order+1) as status_order,
@group_leader:=if(@pre_st!=status,id,@group_leader) as group_leader,
@pre_st:=status
from statuses,(select @st_order:=-1, @pre_st:=-1, @group_leader:=-1) val
```

This sql gives you the output

> id,
>   status,
>   the row number of continues same status,
>   the same status's group leader,
>   useless last column

Given your input, the first four columns output is

> ID|status|status row number|status group leader
>   777| 1 | 0 | 777
>   675| 1 | 1 | 777
>   651| 0 | 0 | 651
>   611| 1 | 0 | 611
>   600| 0 | 0 | 600
>   554| 1 | 0 | 554
>   443| 0 | 0 | 443
>   323| 0 | 1 | 443
>   222| 1 | 0 | 222
>   112| 1 | 1 | 222

So you can do whatever you want in an outer select.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select/16715618#16715618). the order in which multiple uses of a variable in a query are evaluated is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using little logic using sub queries

```
set @cnt=0;
set @id=-1;
SELECT 
    t3.id, t3.status, t3.dup_id AS `group`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id,
            status,
            IF(status = 0, @cnt:=@cnt + 1, @cnt:=0) AS great,
            IF(@cnt = 1, @id:=id, IF(status = 0, @id, - 1)) AS dup_id
    FROM
        statuses) t3
WHERE
    t3.dup_id IN (SELECT 
            t1.dup_id
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                id,
                    status,
                    IF(status = 0, @cnt:=@cnt + 1, @cnt:=0) AS great,
                    IF(@cnt = 1, @id:=id, IF(status = 0, @id, - 1)) AS dup_id
            FROM
                statuses) t1
        GROUP BY t1.dup_id
        HAVING COUNT(t1.dup_id) > 1
            AND t1.dup_id != - 1);
```

Result will be as you expected

```
id  | status | group
----|--------|---------
443 | 0      | 443
323 | 0      | 443
```

Comment: too lengthy, complicated, try once again but in a simple way.