# Define and use a variable with a subquery?

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery, mysql-5.5, user-variables

I know normally ["the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined"](//dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) so we can't safely define and use a variable in the same `select` statement. But what if there's a subquery? As an example, I have something like this:

```
select col1,
       (select min(date_)from t where i.col1=col1) as first_date,
       datediff(date_, (select min(date_)from t where i.col1=col1)
               ) as days_since_first_date,
       count(*) cnt
from t i
where anothercol in ('long','list','of','values')
group by col1,days_since_first_date;
```

Is there a way to use `(select @foo:=min(date_)from t where i.col1=col1)` safely instead of repeating the subquery? If so, could I do it in the `datediff` function or the first time the subquery appears (or either one)?

---

Of course, I could do

```
select col1,
       (select min(date_)from t where i.col1=col1) as first_date,
       date_,
       count(*) cnt
from t i
where anothercol in ('long','list','of','values')
group by col1,date_;
```

and then do some simple postprocessing to get the `datediff`. Or I can write two separate queries. But those don't answer my question, which is whether one can safely define and use the same variable in a query and a subquery.

Comment: This link might help you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select

Answer (score 1):

First, your query doesn't really make sense, because `date_` has no aggregation functions.  You are going to get an arbitrary value.

That said, you *could* repeat the subquery, but I don't see why that would be necessary.  Just use a subquery:

```
select t.col1, t.first_date,
       datediff(date_, first_date),
       count(*)
from (select t.*, (select min(date_) from t where i.col1 = t.col1) as first_date
      from t
      where anothercol in ('long','list', 'of', 'values')
     ) t
group by col1, days_since_first_date;
```

As I mentioned, though, the value of the third column is problematic.

Note:  this does occur additional overhead for materializing the subquery.  However, there is a `group by` anyway, so the data is being read and written multiple times.

Comment: Re grouping and aggregation, note that I am grouping on `days_since_first_date`, which is one-to-one correspondence for each `col1` with `date_`, and also on `col1`. So the grouping should be fine.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which was whether it's safe to define and use the same variable in a subquery and a query.