# User-Defined Variable Assignment difference between MySQL and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Of course, we do our job before and searched this community or the web for similar posts but we found nothing.

**Issue:**

We are not happy with our current hosting provider and have to make change. In the middle of our database switch from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.3, we have recognized a SET handling difference, which works perfect in MySQL.

**SQL code:**

```
SET @sb = 0;

SELECT art,sb
FROM ARTICLE
WHERE(@sb:=sb) > 700 AND @sb <= 1000 >AND art = 'AM';
```

**MySQL result:**

| art | sb |
| --- | --- |
| AM | 900.00 |
| AM | 960.00 |
| AM | 1000.00 |
| AM | 770.00 |
| AM | 800.00 |
| the list is much longer... |  |

**MariaDB result:**

| art | sb |
| --- | --- |
| AM | 770.00 |
| AM | 960.00 |
| AM | 1200.00 |
| AM | 3000.00 |
| only 10 rows... |  |

In fact there is a difference between them.

But we want to know:

1. Can we configure this in MariaDB, that we get the same result in MySQL?
2. Should we replace the Set handling in MariaDB with another one?

Comment: The order of operations within a `SELECT` list or `WHERE` clause has never been defined to be left-to-right, so you shouldn't depend on the assignment happening before reading it a second time.

Comment: Why do you need to use `@sb`? Why can't you use `WHERE sb > 700 AND sm <= 1000`?

Comment: it's just an example. it's historical grown of the Statements. We just want to know if or how we can handle it in MariaDB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923660/why-the-order-of-evaluation-for-expressions-involving-user-variables-is-undefine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

In fact, the [MySQL documentation warns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) about the use of variable assignments inside SQL statements:

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1` evaluates `@a` first and then performs the assignment.

What's more, this is a "feature" that is subject to removal:

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

So you should not rely on that, and rewrite your queries.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) is quite clear on this point:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

That your code ever worked was something of a coincidence.  The reason for such warnings is that behavior may change between releases; or even that the results may be inconsistent between runs on the same database.

You should replace the variables with window functions.  The exact function is a bit unclear.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the results always helps.