# MySQL Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I use this query to rewrite the id number column by date, after a new row is added to the database.
Even if the query runs well I can't fix the error displayed at the end of the query. Any suggestion?

```
 SET @ROW = 0;
 UPDATE `mytable` SET `id` = @ROW := @ROW+1 ORDER BY `date` ASC;
```

`Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.`

I tried to modify the query

```
 set id = "0";
 UPDATE `mytable` SET := id+1 ORDER BY `data` ASC;
```

with no success.

Comment: Yes, look up what the word "Deprecated" means! (TL:DR) ___To mark (a component of a software standard) as obsolete to warn against its use in the future so that it may be phased out.___

Comment: PS: I hope thats not an `id` column you may be using as a foreign key ???

Comment: Setting & reading the same user variable in the same select statement has always been explicitly undefined behaviour. Coding queries trying to do that is a faq. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] [Why the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44751302/3404097) See my comments (re an incorrect answer) at [MySQL - Define a variable within select and use it within the same select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715618/3404097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User variables are mostly superseded with window functions, available in MySQL 8.0.

You can what you ask for with `row_number()`  and the `update`/`join` syntax :

```sql
update mytable t
inner join (select id, row_number() over(order by date, id) new_id from mytable) t1
  on t.id = t1.id
set t.id = t1.new_id
```

[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/JWcasGDJ).

This assumes that `id` is a unique key to start with.

I would still question why you would need to alter what looks like a surrogate primary key. You can compute the row number on the fly in your queries in that's what you want, or use a view :

```sql
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(order by date, id) new_id from mytable t
```

[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/gLJz6e8H)