# Ranking players in SQL database will return always 1 when where id_user is used

Tags: sql, subquery, ranking, rank, row-number

I basically have a table "race" with columns for "id_race", "id_user" and columns for user predictions "pole_position", "1st", "2nd", "3rd" and "fastest_lap". In addition to those columns, each prediction column also has a control column such as "PPC", "1eC", "2eC", "3eC" and "srC". Those control columns are then compared by a query against a "result" table. Then the control columns in race are awarded points for a correct prediction.

[table race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSqHT.jpg)

I want to add up those results per user and then rank them per user. I want to show that rank on the player's user page. I have a query for my SQL which works fine in itself and gives me a list with rank column.

```
SELECT 
    @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, 
    total, 
    id_user 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SUM(PPC + 1eC + 2eC + 3eC + srC ) AS total, 
         id_user 
     FROM 
         race 
     GROUP BY 
         id_user 
     ORDER BY 
         total DESC) T, 
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) a;
```

Output of rank query:

[image: Output]

However when I add the where `id_user` it always gets the first rank. Does anyone have an idea if this can be solved and how I could achieve it to add where to my rank query?

I've already tried filtering. In addition, I have tried to use the `Row_number` function. It also always gives a result of 1 because only 1 user remains after filtering. I am unable to filter out the correct position. So please help!

Comment: please share the sample data and table structure of race table for better debugging.

Comment: `SELECT
@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
total,
id_user
FROM
(
SELECT
SUM(PPC + 1eC + 2eC + 3eC + srC ) AS total,
id_user
FROM race
WHERE id_user = [value of id_user]
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY total DESC
) T, ( SELECT @rownum := 0 ) a;`

Comment: [Why the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44751302/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a variable within select and use it within the same select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a view to extracting the correct rank. Once you use `WHERE` clause, you will get the rank based on the population rather that the subset.

Please find an indicative answer on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pDh-Bs-_) where a `CTE` and `ROW` function are used. The indicative code is:

```
WITH sum_cte AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(PPC + 1EC + 2eC + 3eC + srC) DESC) AS Row, 
    id_user, 
    SUM(PPC + 1EC + 2eC + 3eC + srC) AS total_sum
  FROM race
  GROUP BY id_user)
SELECT Row, id_user, total_sum
FROM sum_cte
WHERE id_user = 1
```

User 1 with the second score will appear with a row valuation 2.

Comment: Oh wow... yes that is wat i was looking for. You are the best. Thanks a lot. I had so many hours in it and didn't see how i could achieve it. Thanks

Comment: You can always accept the answer as correct