# alias in where clause mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing following query in mysql, but it returning 0 rows

```
select * from (select col1 as mycol from tbl) temp where temp.mycol = 5
```

but the following query returning 4 rows

```
select col1 as mycol from tbl where col1 = 5
```

what is wrong with 1st query?

Comment: Those queries look equivalent to me.  Can you reproduce this behavior on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ?

Comment: @Andomar - [I can't reproduce it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7940/2)

Comment: Where are you running your SQL.. in PHP or directly in DB ?

Comment: I am running directly XAMPP and using c#

Comment: And cant there be problem with your C# code ?

Comment: Its working for me ok. Then why you are not.

Comment: Please paste your C# code here

Comment: try to use `select * from (select col1 as mycol from tbl) temp where mycol = 5` remove that `temp` from `temp.mycol`

Comment: Or on the other hand, try `select temp.* ... `

Comment: You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause.

Comment: @Rahul: (Earlier comment) See the link in Lieven's comment. (Later comment) It does, if the alias is defined inside a subquery and you are refering to it outside the subquery - as Mandeep is doing.

Comment: restart the computer and xampp has been solved the problem, thanks to all for you for help

Comment: ha ha ha,what a solution..great.

Comment: i am trying with little change but it not working any suggesion???   select * from (select col1 as 'my col' from tbl) temp where 'temp.my col' = 5

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your problem in your comment:

> i am trying with little change but it not working any suggesion??? select * from (select col1 as 'my col' from tbl) temp where 'temp.my col' = 5 – Mandeep Singh May 30 at 7:48

The problem you are having here is that MySQL is looking for a column called 'temp.my col' but what you really want is the column called `my col` in the table `temp` So you need to do this:

```
select * from (select col1 as `my col` from tbl) temp where `temp`.`my col` = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to an Alias (in MySQL) you need to use HAVING instead of WHERE. Your second line works because you are *not* referring to the alias, but the first statement fails because you *are* referring to an alias with WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine at my End. But I search for your problem and get this thread:

[Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

MySQL also states this :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html

Now I also confused why it works for me?