# Can i use a "virtual column" in Where clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this query:

```
set @last_uid = 0;
set @last_tm = '00:00';
set @last_vid = 0;

SELECT v.*,
     CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
     THEN 
          if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
     ELSE 
          if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
     END  AS newVisitID

FROM visits v
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, visitorid
```

I tried to use the newVisitID column in the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE newVisitID <=5
```

This gives me the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'newVisitID' in 'where clause'
```

Could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference aliases in the `WHERE` clause, but you can reference them in `HAVING`:

```
SELECT v.*,
     CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
     THEN 
          if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
     ELSE 
          if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
     END  AS newVisitID

FROM visits v
HAVING newVisitID <- 5
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, visitorid
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I will go with this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can write out the case statement again, or the easier way is to wrap it and then filter the subquery:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT v.*,
        CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
             THEN if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
             ELSE if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
        END  AS newVisitID
    FROM visits v
) x
WHERE x.newVisitID <= 5
ORDER BY x.timestamp DESC, x.visitorid
```

Answer (score 1):

think you can either use a variable

```
SELECT v.*,
     @newVisitID := CASE WHEN @last_uid = visitorid AND cast( @last_tm as datetime) >= subtime( timestamp, '01:00' )
     THEN 
          if( (@last_tm := timestamp ), @last_vid, @last_vid)
     ELSE 
          if( (@last_uid := visitorid) + (@last_vid := @last_vid+1) +(@last_tm := timestamp ),@last_vid, @last_vid )
     END  AS newVisitID

FROM visits v
where @newVisitID <= 5
ORDER BY timestamp DESC, visitorid
```

or use a subquery if you don't want to repeat your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `A`.`id`        AS `A_id`,
       `A`.`C1`        AS `A_C1`,
       `A`.`C2`        AS `A_C2`,
       `A`.`C3`        AS `A_C3`,
       `A`.`C4`        AS `A_C4`,
       `A`.`C5`        AS `A_C5`,
       CASE
           WHEN `cr`.`C1` is not null AND `cr`.`C2` <= `A`.`C2`
               THEN `cr`.`C1`
           WHEN `cr`.`C1` is not null AND `cr`.`C2` > `A`.`C2`
               THEN `cr`.`C3`
           WHEN `cr`.`C1` is not null AND `cr`.`C2` is null
               THEN `cr`.`C1`
           WHEN `cr`.`C1` is null
               THEN `cr`.`C3`
           END                         AS `businessUnit` FROM `T1` `A`
         LEFT JOIN `T2` `bc` ON `bc`.`A’s_id` = `A`.`id`
         LEFT JOIN `T3` `cr` ON `cr`.`C4` = `bc`.`C2` WHERE `A`.`C5` = ?   AND businessUnit is not null   AND businessUnit IN (?, ?)
```

Could someone help me understand why I always get below error. I am using TypeORM to generate above query and trying to find and count the results. Count is important for pagination.

```
Error:  ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column businessUnit in 'where clause'
```