# Assigned query variable not recognized

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of items which each have latitude and longitude values to allow me to calculate distances.

I'm trying the following but it returns: `Unknown column distance in where clause`:

```
select  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('53.993252') ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) 
- radians('-0.432470') ) 
+ sin( radians('53.993252') ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from items where distance < 1000
```

Comment: [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('53.993252') ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) 
- radians('-0.432470') ) 
+ sin( radians('53.993252') ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from items having distance < 1000
```

`WHERE` doesnt see aliases use `HAVING`.

Comment: Hmmm I was afraid of that, which leads me to the bigger question... I'll post it as a separate question - many thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS('53.993252')) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS('-0.432470')) + SIN(RADIANS('53.993252')) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance
  FROM items)t
WHERE distance < 1000;
```