# SELECT field as mytest WHERE mytest IS NULL - field "mytest" not found?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to use a selected field's named alias in a where clause, yet the database complains about being unable to find said field.

**Query:**

```
SELECT somefunction(myfield) as mytest, myotherfield as mytest2
FROM database.table
WHERE mytest IS NULL OR mytest2 IS NULL
```

**Expectation:** The db would simply test the result of `somefunction(myfield)` or `mytest` for being NULL

**Result**: The db cannot find `mytest` or `mytest2`

Is there something i am missing; why would something like this not work?

Comment: There's no "FROM table"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SELECT somefunction(myfield) as mytest, myotherfield as mytest2 FROM
>   **table** WHERE mytest IS NULL OR mytest2 IS NULL

EDIT: Sorry table.

Possible duplicate:

[Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

**Answer:**

You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

Copied from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: I can't comment since i'm below 50 rep ;)

Comment: While the answer references MySQL, it is applicable to DB2.