# Stored Procedures error unknown column mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm getting this error when I try to run a stored procedure.

```
mysql> call get_nearby;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'longRadius' in 'where clause'

Here is the sql to create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_nearby() BEGIN SET @lat = 10; set @long = 12;
SELECT id, 
  @long - radius / abs(cos(radians(@lat)) * 69) as longRadius, 
  (radius/69) as latRadius
FROM area
WHERE longitude between @long + longRadius and @long - longRadius
AND latitude between @lat + latRadius and @long - latRadius;
END
```

I have no idea why it's not recognising the stated column name. For the moment, I have set @lat, and @long at the start to simplify testing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use column aliases in the where clause. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/4843530.

Comment: Tip of today: use a derived table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in the where clause. You could convert that where clause to a "having" clause and then that will let you use the aliases.  You can get more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942592/4843530) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

From the Mysql docs:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

You can also either restate the computation in the where clause, or use a subquery.