# Creating an alias using math result of 2 other aliases

Tags: mysql, select, alias

I'm trying to subtract 2 aliases in order to create another alias but am getting an "unknown column" error.

Here is my SQL:

```
select o.id, o.name,
     (select sum(l.source_expense)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `expense`,
     (select sum(a.buyer_revenue)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.refunded=0
        and a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `revenue`,
     `revenue` - `expense` as `profit`
     from {$this->sql_table} as o
```

Basically, I'd like to create a `profit` alias by subtracting `revenue` from `expense`. The reason is that I'm using datatables and want the column to be sortable. I already know I can easily do this with PHP.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit - I've attempted the answers below and am getting an "Each derived table should have alias" error from PHPStorm, and a syntax error when attempting to run the query.

Heres the new query:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.expense, t.revenue, t.revenue - t.expense as profit
from(select o.id, o.name,
     (select sum(l.source_expense)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `expense`,
     (select sum(a.buyer_revenue)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.refunded=0
        and a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `revenue`
     from {$this->sql_table} as o
 ) as t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it with another select , then the aliases will be available for uses of mathematical calculation :

```
SELECT t.id,o.name,t.expense,t.revenue,
       t.revenue -t.expense as `profit`
FROM (Your Query Here) t
```

Comment: Same as other answer, getting error - "each derived table should have alias"

Comment: @kjdion84 Post your full query, I'll tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @kjdion84 You are selecting `O.<Column>` in the outer query instead of `T.Column>` , (id and name) , fix that and try again

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your query inside a subquery.

```
SELECT 
t.*,
t.`revenue` - t.`expense` as `profit`
FROM 
(
select o.id, o.name,
     (select sum(l.source_expense)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `expense`,
     (select sum(a.buyer_revenue)
        from `assignments` as a
        left join `leads` as l on (l.id = a.lead_id)
        where a.refunded=0
        and a.{$this->sql_column}=o.id
        and l.date_created between {$this->date_from} and {$this->date_to}
        and find_in_set(l.vertical_id, '".implode(',', $this->app_user->verticals)."')
     ) as `revenue`
     from {$this->sql_table} as o
) AS t
```

**Note:**

You can only use column aliases in `GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING` clauses.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to
>   refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed
>   because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet
>   be determined.

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: Getting error - "each derived table should have alias"

Comment: I've used alias. Did you try the full query that I've posted? @kjdion84

Comment: The refference and the quote you provided are talking about the `WHERE` clause, the OP asked about using the aliases inside the `SELECT` statement .

Comment: I tried to focus on the scope of the usage of `alias`. There's nothing wrong with that (may be). It would have been better if I would also mention the execution order of sql statements. @sagi