# Mysql Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.`ID`, t1.`notification_type`, t1.`notification_by`, t1.`notification_by_username`, 
                t1.`notification_status`, t1.`notification_date`, t1.`school_key`, t1.`class_key`, t1.`post_key`, t1.`extra`, t1.`class_info`, t1.`class_subject`,
                (SELECT `notification_last_check` 
                       FROM data_users.account_info t2
                       WHERE t2.`user_key` = t1.`notification_by` LIMIT 1) AS `notification_last_check` 
       FROM `14754931095281411` t1 
       WHERE t1.`notification_status` = '10' 
                AND t1.`notification_date` > t2.`notification_last_check`   
       ORDER BY `notification_date` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 't2.notification_last_check' in 'where clause'

why im getting the above error ?

Comment: You can't compare: AND t1.`notification_date` > t2.`notification_last_check` because t2.`notification_last_check` is out of scope.

Comment: OK so whats we can do ?

Comment: If you need apply this comparation, your subquery must be placed in WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks dude worked good

Comment: Because you're newbie, if an answer accomplishes your question, please accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: @AxelH: IMHO the starting point of view is different. Here there's an error not for alias but because our OP has used an information present in a subquery of field list

Comment: @JoeTaras Accepted

Comment: @JoeTaras, sorry, I mark the duplicated based on the comment in my answer. Since correcting the scope wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
SELECT
    t1.`ID`, t1.`notification_type`, t1.`notification_by`,
    t1.`notification_by_username`, 
    t1.`notification_status`, t1.`notification_date`, t1.`school_key`,
    t1.`class_key`, t1.`post_key`, t1.`extra`, t1.`class_info`,
    t1.`class_subject`,
    (SELECT `notification_last_check` 
    FROM data_users.account_info t2
    WHERE t2.`user_key` = t1.`notification_by` LIMIT 1) AS `notification_last_check` 
FROM `14754931095281411` t1 
WHERE t1.`notification_status` = '10' 
AND t1.`notification_date` > (SELECT `notification_last_check` 
    FROM data_users.account_info t3
    WHERE t3.`user_key` = t1.`notification_by` LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY `notification_date` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: this is the easiest answer

Comment: I don't find this clean. You are doing twice the same select, this could be bad to performance. A join would be simpler.

Comment: @AxelH: But with JOIN operation you must apply a DISTINCT because the occurence of account_info are more than one. So distinct is very weight

Comment: Only a DISTINCT on the sub query used to do the join. I find it to be more efficient in general to return a distinct result of 1k row instead of doing 1k select call (2k in your case).

Comment: I have write the left join in my answer, but this depends on the number of line in general.

Answer (score 0):

`t2` exist only in the sub-query scope (the query in your select).

So here you don't have `t2.notification_last_check` but only `notification_last_check`

```
SELECT ...,
            (SELECT `notification_last_check` 
                   FROM data_users.account_info t2
                   WHERE t2.`user_key` = t1.`notification_by` LIMIT 1) AS `notification_last_check` 
   FROM `14754931095281411` t1 
   WHERE t1.`notification_status` = '10' 
            AND t1.`notification_date` > `notification_last_check`  -- Remove the alias t2
   ORDER BY `notification_date` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Then of course, I should mention that this will failed because you can't use an alias in `WHERE` clause. Only in `GROUPB BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`. You could use `HAVING` to set this condition, read about this one if you don't know it already.

And other solution would be to use a inner join (a small change is needed)

```
SELECT ...,
       t3.`notification_last_check` 
   FROM `14754931095281411` t1 
   LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT t2.`user_key`, `notification_last_check` 
                  FROM data_users.account_info t2 
         ) t3 On t3.`user_key` = t1.`notification_by
   WHERE t1.`notification_status` = '10' 
   AND t1.`notification_date` > t3.`notification_last_check` 
   ORDER BY t1.`notification_date` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'notification_last_check' in 'where clause'

Comment: @SaefMyth My bad, forgot to precise that you can't use an alias in a `WHERE`, only in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`, the last one could do it, but read about it

Comment: @SaefMyth, I have write the join solution if you want to try this. This might have some different performance (in good or bad)

Comment: I tried it your query took >> 0.0010 seconds. 
the sub-query took >> 0.0006 seconds. on 20 record table.

Comment: @SaefMyth Well, since this took only 1ms, I would not fear performance ;) and this difference is not relevant enough since this could be cause by the thread scheduler of the system. But this will depends on the rows number.

Comment: i think your query will be effective when the rows more than 1000 ,, but for my requirement probably user will not have 1000 notification  at the moment ,, i will consider this solution when user have more records  to query from. thanks anyway

Comment: @SaefMyth If you have time, just use a loop to generate fake data. But the solutions work fine, use the query that's the more readable to futur maintenance.